# Comparar Duas datas e hora

Tags: java, data

Bom dia galera, estou tentando comparar duas datas mas não estou obtendo sucesso. Eu tenho 2 datas: `dataAtual` e `dataPedido`. O que eu quero fazer é que se a dataAtual for igual a dataPedido e se a hora atual for maior que 11:00 AM aparece uma mensagem. Tentei fazer isso mas nao deu certo:

```
public void getDateTime(Date dataPedido, Date dataSistema) {
        try {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            Date horaAtual = new Date();
            String horaMaxima = "11:00";
            dateFormat.format(horaAtual);

            Date horaMax = null;
            horaMax = dateFormat.parse(horaMaxima);

            if (horaAtual.getTime() > horaMax.getTime() && dataPedido.compareTo(dataSistema) == 0) {
                System.err.println("HORA ATUAL MAIOR, nao pode fazer");
                horarioComparacao = false;

            } else {
                System.err.println("HORA ATUAL Menor, pode fazer");
                horarioComparacao = true;

            }
            System.err.println("HORA MAXIMA: " + horaMax);

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(frmPedidos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você usar a classe *Calendar* tudo fica mais simples.

Escreva um método para converter um objecto *Date* em *Calendar* com a opção de *"zerar"* a parte do *Time*.

```
public static Calendar DateToCalendar(Date date, boolean setTimeToZero){ 
    Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendario.setTime(date);
    if(setTimeToZero){
        calendario.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        calendario.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        calenario.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendario.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    }
    return calendario;
}
```

Suponho que quando diz *"se a dataAtual for igual a dataPedido..."* está a considerar que elas são iguais independente da hora.

Escreva um método para testar as condições:

```
public boolean possoProcessarPedido(Date dataPedido) {

    Calendar dataAtualTimeZero = DateToCalendar(new Date(), true);
    Calendar dataPedidoTimeZero = DateToCalendar(dataPedido, true);

    if(dataAtualTimeZero.compareTo(dataPedidoTimeZero) != 0){
        // A data do pedido e a data atual são diferentes: pode processar
        return true;
    }

    Calendar dataAtual = DateToCalendar(new Date(), false);
    Calendar dataAtualAs11Horas  = DateToCalendar(new Date(), true);
    dataAtualAs11Horas.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);

    if(dataAtual.after(dataAtualAs11Horas){
        //As datas são iguias mas já passa das 11 horas: não pode processar
        return false;
    }
    // As datas são iguais e é antes das 11 horas: pode processar
    return true;
}
```

Use o método da seguinte forma:

```
if(possoProcessarPedido(dataPedido){
    // código para processar pedido
}
```

Comment: Alterei o código para simplificar a condição que verifica se já passou das 11 horas

Answer (score 4):

Apenas para complementar as respostas anteriores, a partir do Java 8 você pode usar a [API `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html).

Há alguns detalhes a se considerar ao trabalhar com a API antiga (`java.util.Date`) e a nova simultaneamente, pois alguns conceitos são diferentes. Segue então uma breve explicação sobre `Date`, para que possamos entender a conversão desta para as classes do `java.time`.

#### Sobre `java.util.Date`

`java.util.Date`, apesar do nome, não é exatamente uma data propriamente dita, pois ela não representa um único valor de dia, mês e ano. Ela representa na verdade um [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052): um número gigante (do tipo `long`) contendo a quantidade de milissegundos desde o Unix Epoch (`1970-01-01T00:00Z`, ou *"1 de janeiro de 1970, à meia noite, em [UTC](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempo_Universal_Coordenado)"*).

O timestamp é um valor, digamos, "universal". Neste exato momento, em qualquer lugar do mundo, o timestamp é o mesmo. Em Java, basta chamar `System.currentTimeMillis()` e você terá o timestamp correspondente ao instante atual. Eu rodei agora e o valor retornado foi `1534249967760`. E este valor é o mesmo no mundo todo: qualquer computador, em qualquer fuso horário do mundo, obteria este mesmo número se chamasse `System.currentTimeMillis()` no mesmo instante que eu.

Só que este valor (`1534249967760`) pode representar uma data/hora diferente em cada fuso horário. Em São Paulo, este timestamp equivale a **14 de agosto de 2018, às 09:32:47.760 da manhã**. Em Londres, equivale ao mesmo dia (14 de agosto), mas neste mesmo instante o horário lá é **13:32** (1 da tarde). E em Samoa já são **01:32** (1 da manhã) do dia **15**.

Podemos ver melhor isso imprimindo o `Date` (com `System.out.println` ou com qualquer API de log). Ao imprimí-lo, este é convertido para o timezone *default* da JVM, por isso o resultado contém uma data e hora específicas. Mas o valor do `Date` não muda. No código abaixo eu uso a classe `java.util.TimeZone` para mudar o timezone *default*:

```
// código rodado quando o timestamp atual é 1534249967760
Date date = new Date();
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
System.out.println(date.getTime() + "=" + date);
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
System.out.println(date.getTime() + "=" + date);
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Pacific/Apia"));
System.out.println(date.getTime() + "=" + date);
```

Eu mudei o timezone *default* 3 vezes, para São Paulo, Londres e Apia (que é o timezone de Samoa) e imprimi o `Date` e o valor de `getTime()` (que retorna o valor do timestamp). O resultado é:

```
1534249967760=Tue Aug 14 09:32:47 BRT 2018
1534249967760=Tue Aug 14 13:32:47 BST 2018
1534249967760=Wed Aug 15 01:32:47 WSST 2018
```

Repare que o timestamp não muda, mas a data e hora sim. Isso acontece porque ao imprimir o `Date`, ele converte o timestamp para o timezone *default*, resultando em uma data e hora diferentes em cada caso. Mas estes valores de data e hora não fazem parte do `Date`, somente o timestamp.

Por isso, para converter um `Date` para uma data (um dia, mês e ano específicos), você deve escolher um fuso horário (que a API chama de **timezone**). O que acontece com `Calendar` é que internamente ele usa o timezone *default* da JVM e já calcula os valores para o dia, mês, ano, horas, minutos, segundos etc.

Mas no `java.time` isso não acontece automaticamente e você deve especificar qual timezone deve ser usado.

Com isso, podemos prosseguir para a conversão de `Date` para as classes do `java.time`.

#### Converter `Date` para uma data e hora específicas

Primeiro convertemos o `Date` para `java.time.Instant`, que é a classe que representa um timestamp. Para isso foi adicionado o método `toInstant()` (disponível a partir do Java 8):

```
Date data = new Date();
// criar Instant (com o mesmo valor do timestamp de Date)
Instant instant = data.toInstant();
```

A partir do `Instant`, podemos convertê-lo para um timezone qualquer, usando a classe `java.time.ZoneId` (que representa um timezone). O resultado será um `java.time.ZonedDateTime` (uma classe que representa uma data e hora em um timezone específico). Exemplo:

```
Date data = new Date();
ZonedDateTime zdt = data.toInstant()
    // converter o Instant para um timezone
    .atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
```

O nome do timezone (`America/Sao_Paulo`) segue a nomenclatura da [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), que é a base de dados usada pela JVM para obter informações do timezone (como início e fim do horário de verão, por exemplo, assim ela consegue saber exatamente a data e hora correspondente ao timestamp).

Se você quiser usar o timezone *default* da JVM (e assim simular o que `Calendar` faz), pode usar `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. Fica a seu critério.

Para obter a data atual, basta usar o método `now()`:

```
ZonedDateTime agora = ZonedDateTime.now();
```

Isso cria um `ZonedDateTime` contendo a data e hora atual, no timezone *default* da JVM. Se quiser usar um timezone específico, basta passar o `ZoneId`:

```
ZonedDateTime agora = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
```

Com isso você obtém os valores corretos para a data e hora no timezone que quiser, sem depender da configuração da JVM (que pode mudar sem você saber, pois qualquer parte do código pode chamar `TimeZone.setDefault`, afetando todas as aplicações que rodam na mesma JVM).

Para fazer as comparações necessárias, basta usar o método `equals` (para verificar igualdade) e `isAfter` (para saber se um determinado instante ocorre depois de outro).

A primeira comparação leva em conta apenas a data (ignorando a hora), então você deve usar o método `toLocalDate()`, que retorna um `java.time.LocalDate` (uma classe que só possui dia, mês e ano), assim a comparação é feita ignorando o horário.

Depois, para a segunda comparação, basta usar o método `toLocalTime()`, que retorna um `java.time.LocalTime` (uma classe que só possui hora, minuto, segundo e frações de segundo). Em seguida comparamos com outro `java.time.Localtime` cujo valor é 11:00.

*Aliás, esta é outra característica do `java.time`: várias classes especializadas para cada situação (uma que só representa data, outra só para as horas, outra para data e hora com timezone, etc).*

Enfim, o código ficaria assim (assumindo que você quer usar o timezone *default* da JVM):

```
public boolean possoProcessarPedido(Date dataPedido) {
    ZonedDateTime pedido = dataPedido.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    ZonedDateTime dataAtual = ZonedDateTime.now();

    // comparar somente a data (ignora o horário)
    if (! dataAtual.toLocalDate().equals(pedido.toLocalDate())) {
        // data do pedido e data atual são diferentes - pode processar
        return true;
    }
    // se não entrou no if acima é porque as datas são iguais

    // verificar se já passou das 11:00
    if (dataAtual.toLocalTime().isAfter(LocalTime.of(11, 0))) {
        // passou das 11:00 - não pode processar
        return false;
    }

    // não passou das 11:00 - pode processar
    return true;
}
```

Se ao invés do timezone *default*, você quiser usar um timezone específico, basta usar o `ZoneId` correspondente, conforme já explicado anteriormente.

#### Java 6 e 7

Para Java 6 e 7, você pode usar o [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), um *backport* do `java.time`. Basicamente, possui as mesmas classes (`Instant`, `LocalDate`, `ZoneId`, etc) e métodos do Java 8, com uma diferença: no Java 8 as classes estão no pacote `java.time`, e no *backport* elas ficam em `org.threeten.bp`.

Outra diferença é que no Java 6 e 7 a classe `Date` não possui o método `toInstant()` e a conversão deve ser feita pela classe `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils`:

```
Date date = new Date();
Instant instant = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(date);
```

O restante do código ficaria igual.

#### Java <= 5

Para Java <= 5, é possível usar o [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time). Esta API é o "predecessor" do `java.time`, e muitos conceitos são parecidos (até alguns nomes de classes são os mesmos), [embora ela não seja 100% igual](http://blog.joda.org/2009/11/why-jsr-310-isn-joda-time_4941.html).

O código fica bem parecido: ao invés de `ZonedDateTime`, usamos a classe `org.joda.time.DateTime` - aliás, todas as classes abaixo (`LocalDate`, `Localtime`, etc), embora tenham os mesmos nomes do `java.time`, estão no pacote `org.joda.time`:

```
public boolean possoProcessarPedido(Date dataPedido) {
    DateTime pedido = new DateTime(dataPedido);
    DateTime dataAtual = new DateTime();

    // comparar somente a data
    if (!dataAtual.toLocalDate().equals(pedido.toLocalDate())) {
        // data do pedido e data atual são diferentes - pode processar
        return true;
    }
    // se não entrou no if acima é porque as datas são iguais

    // verificar se já passou das 11:00
    if (dataAtual.toLocalTime().isAfter(new LocalTime(11, 0))) {
        // passou das 11:00 - não pode processar
        return false;
    }

    // não passou das 11:00 - pode processar
    return true;
}
```

Este código usa o timezone *default* da JVM para converter o `Date` para `DateTime`. Se quiser usar um timezone específico, use a classe `org.joda.time.DateTimeZone`:

```
DateTimeZone timezone = DateTimeZone.forID("America/Sao_Paulo");
DateTime pedido = new DateTime(dataPedido, timezone);
DateTime dataAtual = new DateTime(timezone);
```

O método `forID` recebe o nome do timezone, também seguindo a nomenclatura da [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

Answer (score 2):

Acho melhor vc usar a classe calendar

```
Calendar dataAtual = new GregorianCalendar();   
    Calendar dataMAxima = new GregorianCalendar();   
    dataAtual.setTime(new Date());
    dataMAxima.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
    dataMAxima.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    dataMAxima.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

nela vc tem metodos de comparação, acima eu explico com passar uma data e como setar uma data importante é setar hora, minuto e segundo