# Como é feito o cálculo do timestamp?

Tags: data, timestamp

O *timestamp* é a representação numérica de uma data e é bastante utilizado nas linguagens de programação e em banco de dados. Quero saber:

Como é feito esse cálculo?

Existe alguma padronização para esse cálculo uma ISO ou algo parecido?

Já ouvi falar em `unix timestamp`. Existem outros sabores de timestamp?

Comment: Não seria o número de segundos desde uma data, se não me engano desde 1970??

Comment: O conceito utilizado em um timestamp é do Dia Juliano, proposto por Joseph Justus Scaliger em 1583. A data é representada pela parte inteira indicando a quantidade de dias decorridos a partir de uma determinada data. A parte fracionária indica o instante do dia. Assim o número de ponto flutuante identifica um determinado instante. O Unix timestamp, ou epoch, é um pouco diferente pois é um inteiro indicando o número de segundos decorridos desde dia 01.Jan.1970 às 00:00:00 do Tempo Universal Coordenado (UTC).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## O que é o *timestamp do unix*?

> Como é feito esse cálculo?
>
> Existe alguma padronização para esse cálculo uma ISO ou algo parecido?

O *timestamp do unix* corresponde ao número de segundos desde a meia-noite do dia 01/01/1970 no fuso horário UTC sem considerar os segundos bissextos (tal como mencionado na [resposta do ctgPi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70486/132)). Para simplificar, vamos denominar este momento no tempo de ponto zero. Assim, o *timestamp do unix* é o número de segundos desde o ponto zero.

O *timestamp do unix* costuma ser representado de várias formas:

- Quando representado como um inteiro de 32 bits com sinal, o *timestamp do unix* pode representar datas entre 13/12/1901 20:45:52 até 19/01/2038 03:14:07, ambas no UTC. O MySQL por exemplo, [usa o tipo `TIMESTAMP` armazenado assim](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html), e por causa disso é susceptível ao [bug do ano 2038](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2012620/540552), o que é mais-ou-menos uma versão Unix do infame [bug do ano 2000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem).
- Quando representado como um inteiro de 32 bits sem sinal, ele pode representar datas entre 01/01/1970 00:00:00 até 07/02/2106 06:28:15, novamente ambas no UTC.
- Quando representado por um número de 64 bits com sinal, ele pode representar datas entre 27/01/-292277022657 08:29:52 até 04/12/292277026596 15:30:07 (desconsiderando-se o fato de que antes de 1582 o calendário aplicado não era o gregoriano). Isso é um intervalo grande o bastante para incluir todo o período de tempo desde muito antes do Big Bang até um ponto num futuro tão distante tal que [o universo já será muito diferente de como o conhecemos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_fate_of_the_universe).

Há várias formas de se converter de *timestamp do unix* para uma data e vice-versa. Algumas formas são mais simples, outras mais complicadas. Mas o que importa é que todas elas cheguem no mesmo resultado em todos os casos.
Então, eis o algoritmo para obter uma data/hora a partir do *timestamp do unix*:

## Algoritmo de conversão de *timestamp do unix* para data/hora:

1. Se pegarmos o *timestamp do unix* e dividirmos por 60, o quociente da divisão (vamos denominá-lo de `minutosUnix`) será o número de minutos desde o ponto zero. O resto será a quantidade de segundos transcorridos no minuto. Para valores negativos do *timestamp do unix*, aonde o quociente é zero ou negativo e o resto é negativo (mas não zero), deve-se somar 60 ao resto obtido e subtrair 1 do quociente obtido.
2. Se pegarmos o `minutosUnix` e dividirmos por 60, o quociente da divisão (vamos denominá-lo de `horasUnix`) será o número de horas desde o ponto zero. O resto será a quantidade de minutos transcorridos na hora. Para valores negativos de `minutosUnix`, aonde o quociente é zero ou negativo e o resto é negativo (mas não zero), deve-se somar 60 ao resto obtido e subtrair 1 do quociente obtido.
3. Se pegarmos o `horasUnix` e dividirmos por 24, o quociente da divisão (vamos denominá-lo de `diasUnix`) será o número de dias desde o ponto zero. O resto será a quantidade de horas transcorridas no dia. Para valores negativos de `horasUnix`, aonde o quociente é zero ou negativo e o resto é negativo (mas não zero), deve-se somar 24 ao resto obtido e subtrair 1 do quociente obtido.

A partir daqui, a situação fica um pouco mais complicada. O calendário gregoriano se repete a cada 400 anos, uma vez que temos anos bissextos a cada 4 anos (os anos cujo número é divisível por 4) mas com três exceções, que a saber, são os anos divisíveis por 100 mas não por 400.

Desta forma, cada ciclo de 400 anos no calendário gregoriano tem 146097 dias, pois:

```
    ((365 * 4) + 1) * 100 - 3 = 146097
```

4. Vamos denominar como `ciclosDe400Anos` o quociente da divisão de `diasUnix` por 146097 e como `diasEm400Anos` o resto. Para valores negativos de `diasUnix`, aonde o quociente é zero ou negativo e o resto é negativo (mas não zero), deve-se somar 146097 ao resto obtido e subtrair 1 do quociente obtido.

Neste ciclo de 400 anos, com as três exceções citadas, temos ciclos de 4 anos com três anos não-bissextos e um ano bissexto, totalizando 1461 dias. Isso significa que nestes 400 anos há 97 ciclos de 4 anos com 1461 dias e 3 ciclos de 4 anos com 1460 dias. Considerando que o ciclo de 4 anos de número 0 começa em 01/01/1970 e termina em 31/12/1973, então os ciclos de 4 anos que tem 1460 dias dentro destes 400 anos são os ciclos de número 32 - que corresponde ao ciclo de 2098-2101 contendo o ano 2100, o ciclo de número 57 - que corresponde ao ciclo de 2198-2201 contendo o ano 2200 e o ciclo de número 82 - que corresponde ao ciclo de 2298-2301 contendo o ano 2300. Estes três ciclos estão sem o dia 29 de fevereiro, mas podemos acrescentar artificialmente os dias 29 de fevereiro faltantes ao somar um dia a partir de 01/03/2100, mais um dia a partir de 01/03/2200 e mais um a partir de 01/03/2300, fazendo todos os ciclos terem 1461 dias. Assim, o dia 29 de fevereiro pulado (que na verdade é 1º de março), ocorre após serem transcorridos 789 dias em cada um destes ciclos de 4 anos (dois anos de 365 dias mais janeiro de 31 dias mais fevereiro de 28 dias = 789 dias). Desta forma:

5. Incrementamos `diasEm400Anos` se o valor for maior ou igual a `(32 * 1461 + 789)`, incrementamos novamente se for maior ou igual a `(57 * 1461 + 789)` e incrementamos uma terceira vez se for maior ou igual a `(82 * 1461 + 789)`. Isso dará conta dos três dias 29 de fevereiro pulados, e fará o calendário resultante se repetir a cada quatro anos de 1461 dias e os três dias introduzidos artificialmente nunca ocorrerão.
6. Vamos denominar como `ciclosDeQuatroAnos` o quociente da divisão de `diasEmQuatroAnos` por 1461 e como `diasEmQuatroAnos` o resto.

Para reduzir o período para um ano ao invés de quatro, podemos fazer algo semelhante ao que foi feito no passo 5 para considerar os três dias 29 de fevereiro pulados nos quatro anos. Considerando que no ciclo de quatro anos iniciado em 1970 (o mesmo valerá para todos os demais), o primeiro 29 de fevereiro pulado (em 1970) seria após transcorridos 59 dias (31 em janeiro e 28 em fevereiro), o de 1971 seria após 424 dias e o de 1973 após 1155 dias, então:

7. Incrementamos `diasEmQuatroAnos` se o valor for maior ou igual a 59, incrementamos novamente se for maior ou igual a 425 e incrementamos uma terceira vez se for maior ou igual a 1157. Isso dará conta dos três dias 29 de fevereiro pulados, e fará o calendário resultante se repetir a cada um ano de 366 dias. O número 425 é usado ao invés de 424 por causa do dia acrescentado após o 59. O número 1157 é usado ao invés do 1155 por causa dos dois dias acrescentados no 59 e no 425.

Agora, teremos anos de 366 dias, já pulados todos os dias 29 de fevereiro que deveriam ser pulados e teremos um ciclo de 4 anos com 1464 dias (incluindo os três dias acrescentados artificialmente que nunca ocorrerão). Assim, podemos finalmente obter o ano:

8. Vamos denominar como `anoEmQuatroAnos` o quociente da divisão de `diasEmQuatroAnos` por 366 e como `diasNoAno` o resto.
9. O ano será a soma de `anoEmQuatroAnos`, mais quatro vezes o valor de `ciclosDeQuatroAnos`, mais quatrocentas vezes o valor de `ciclosDe400Anos` mais 1970.

E finalmente, obtemos o dia e o mês:

10. Constrói-se uma tabela com o número de dias em cada mês, que corresponde a `[31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]` e conta-se qual dia de qual mês corresponde o valor de `diasNoAno`, subtraindo de `diasNoAno` os dias de cada mês até que não seja mais possível subtrair. O mês em que não for possível subtrair é o mês correspondente ao *timestamp do unix* dado. O número de dias restantes mais um é o dia correspondente ao *timestamp do unix* dado.

O algoritmo delineado acima só funciona para datas do [calendário gregoriano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregorian_calendar). Isso significa que ele produzirá resultados incorretos para *timestamps do unix* correspondentes a datas anteriores a [adoção deste calendário](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adoption_of_the_Gregorian_calendar).

Após a implementação disso, se você quiser, poderá fazer a conversão de fuso horário para algum que não seja UTC. Novamente, vale frisar que os segundos bissextos são desconsiderados.

## Algoritmo de conversão de data/hora para *timestamp do unix*:

Para fazer o procedimento inverso:

1. Subtraia 1970 do ano.
2. Pegamos o ano subtraído de 1970 e dividimos por 400, denominando o quociente da divisão de `periodosDe400Anos` e o resto de `anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos`. Para valores aonde o ano subtraído de 1970 é negativo e o quociente é zero ou negativo e o resto é negativo (mas não zero), deve-se somar 400 ao resto obtido e subtrair 1 do quociente obtido.
3. Pegamos o `anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos` e dividimos por 4, denominando o quociente da divisão de `periodosDe4AnosNos400` e o resto de `anoNoPeriodoDe4Anos`.
4. Calculamos o número de dias nos anos anteriores no período de quatro anos (e denominamos isso de `diasNosAnosAnterioresDoPeriodoDe4Anos`) ao olhar para o valor de `anoNoPeriodoDe4Anos`. Serão 365 dias para cada ano anterior. Se o valor de `anoNoPeriodoDe4Anos` for 3 (ou seja, o último do período de 4 anos), então o ano imediatamente anterior era bissexto (desconsiderando por ora os casos dos anos 2100, 2200 e 2300), e por causa disso, deve-se somar ainda mais um dia neste caso.
5. Calculamos o número de dias transcorridos no ano ao pegar o número do dia, subtrair 1 e somar na tabela de número de meses o número de dias em todos os meses anteriores no ano. A tabela é `[31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]`. Note que estou considerando fevereiro como tendo 28 dias. Isso será corrigido posteriormente se necessário.
6. Calcula-se o número de dias desde 01/01/1970 (ainda necessitando correção posterior por causa de anos bissextos). Isso é computado como a soma do número de dias no ano, `diasNosAnosAnterioresDoPeriodoDe4Anos`, `periodosDe4AnosNos400` vezes 1461 e `periodosDe400Anos` vezes 146097.
7. Aplica-se a correção dos anos bissextos. Se `anoNoPeriodoDe4Anos` for igual a 2 e o mês for março para frente, soma-se um dia. Se `anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos` for maior que 130, ou igual a 130 em março ou depois, soma-se um dia. O mesmo vale para os anos de número 230 e 330. Com isso obtém-se o número total de dias desde 01/01/1970.
8. O *timestamp do unix* resultante é o número de segundos, mais o número de minutos vezes 60, mais o número de horas vezes 3600 (1 hora = 3600 segundos), mais o número de dias desde 01/01/1970 vezes 86400 (1 dia = 86400 segundos).

Novamente, o algoritmo delineado acima só funciona para datas do calendário gregoriano.

## Algoritmo para se obter o dia da semana a partir do *timestamp do unix*:

Para obter-se o dia da semana a partir do *timestamp do unix*, o procedimento também é simples:

1. Divida o *timestamp do unix* por 86400 para obter o número de dias desde 01/01/1970 ao invés de o número de segundos. Para valores negativos do *timestamp do unix*, aonde o quociente é zero ou negativo e o resto é negativo (mas não zero), deve-se subtrair 1 do quociente obtido.
2. Some 4 dias e obtenha o resto da divisão por 7. Para valores negativos de números de dias (após somar 4), aonde o quociente é zero ou negativo e o resto é negativo (mas não zero), deve-se somar 7 ao resto obtido a fim de torná-lo positivo.
3. Mapeie o número resultante de forma que 0 seja domingo, 1 seja segunda-feira, etc.

## Implementação:

Aqui vai uma implementação estilo *reinventar a roda* em Java, em especial no construtor que recebe como parâmetro o `timestampUnix`. O método `getTimestamp()` faz o processo inverso. O método `getDiaDaSemana()` obtém o dia da semana. Traduzir o código abaixo para outras linguagens de programação deverá ser algo relativamente fácil também:

```java
import java.util.Objects;

public final class DataUTC implements Comparable<DataUTC> {
    private final int segundo;
    private final int minuto;
    private final int hora;
    private final int dia;
    private final int mes;
    private final long ano;

    private static int restoSemSinal(long a, int b) {
        return (int) (a >= 0L
                ? a % b // Positivo.
                : (b + (a % b)) % b); // Negativo.
    }

    private static long divisaoSemSinal(long a, int b) {
        return a >= 0L
                ? a / b // Positivo.
                : (a / b) - (a % b == 0 ? 0 : 1); // Negativo.
    }

    public DataUTC(int segundo, int minuto, int hora, int dia, int mes, long ano) {
        this.segundo = segundo;
        this.minuto = minuto;
        this.hora = hora;
        this.dia = dia;
        this.mes = mes;
        this.ano = ano;
    }

    public DataUTC(long timestampUnix) {
        // Passo 1.
        long minutosUnix = divisaoSemSinal(timestampUnix, 60);
        segundo = restoSemSinal(timestampUnix, 60);

        // Passo 2.
        long horasUnix = divisaoSemSinal(minutosUnix, 60);
        minuto = restoSemSinal(minutosUnix, 60);

        // Passo 3.
        long diasUnix = divisaoSemSinal(horasUnix, 24);
        hora = restoSemSinal(horasUnix, 24);

        // Passo 4.
        long ciclosDe400Anos = divisaoSemSinal(diasUnix, 146097);
        int diasEm400Anos = restoSemSinal(diasUnix, 146097);

        // Passo 5.
        if (diasEm400Anos >= 32 * 1461 + 789) diasEm400Anos++;
        if (diasEm400Anos >= 57 * 1461 + 789) diasEm400Anos++;
        if (diasEm400Anos >= 82 * 1461 + 789) diasEm400Anos++;

        // Passo 6.
        int ciclosDe4Anos = diasEm400Anos / 1461;
        int diasEm4Anos = diasEm400Anos % 1461;

        // Passo 7.
        if (diasEm4Anos >= 59) diasEm4Anos++;
        if (diasEm4Anos >= 425) diasEm4Anos++;
        if (diasEm4Anos >= 1157) diasEm4Anos++;

        // Passo 8.
        int anoEm4Anos = diasEm4Anos / 366;
        int diasNoAno = diasEm4Anos % 366;

        // Passo 9.
        ano = anoEm4Anos + ciclosDe4Anos * 4 + ciclosDe400Anos * 400 + 1970;

        // Passo 10.
        int[] tabelaDeMeses = {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
        int contagemDeMeses = 0;
        while (diasNoAno >= tabelaDeMeses[contagemDeMeses]) {
            diasNoAno -= tabelaDeMeses[contagemDeMeses];
            contagemDeMeses++;
        }
        mes = contagemDeMeses + 1;
        dia = diasNoAno + 1;
    }

    public long getTimestamp() {
        // Passo 1.
        long anosDesde1970 = ano - 1970;

        // Passo 2.
        long periodosDe400Anos = divisaoSemSinal(anosDesde1970, 400);
        int anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos = restoSemSinal(anosDesde1970, 400);

        // Passo 3.
        int periodosDe4AnosNos400 = anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos / 4;
        int anoNoPeriodoDe4Anos = anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos % 4;

        // Passo 4.
        int diasNosAnosAnterioresDoPeriodoDe4Anos = 365 * anoNoPeriodoDe4Anos + (anoNoPeriodoDe4Anos == 3 ? 1 : 0);

        // Passo 5.
        long diasNoAno = dia - 1;
        int[] tabelaDeMeses = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
        for (int i = 0; i < mes - 1; i++) {
            diasNoAno += tabelaDeMeses[i];
        }

        // Passo 6.
        long dias = diasNoAno
                + diasNosAnosAnterioresDoPeriodoDe4Anos
                + periodosDe4AnosNos400 * 1461
                + periodosDe400Anos * 146097;

        // Passo 7.
        if (anoNoPeriodoDe4Anos == 2 && mes > 2) dias++;
        if (anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos > 130 || (anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos == 130 && mes > 2)) dias--;
        if (anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos > 230 || (anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos == 230 && mes > 2)) dias--;
        if (anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos > 330 || (anoNoPeriodoDe400Anos == 330 && mes > 2)) dias--;

        // Passo 8.
        return segundo + 60 * minuto + 60 * 60 * hora + 60 * 60 * 24 * dias;
    }

    public static enum DiaDaSemana {
        DOMINGO, SEGUNDA_FEIRA, TERCA_FEIRA, QUARTA_FEIRA, QUINTA_FEIRA, SEXTA_FEIRA, SABADO;
    }

    public DiaDaSemana getDiaDaSemana() {
        // Passo 1.
        long diasDesde1970 = divisaoSemSinal(getTimestamp(), 86400);

        // Passo 2.
        int diaDaSemana = restoSemSinal(diasDesde1970 + 4, 7);

        // Passo 3.
        return DiaDaSemana.values()[diaDaSemana];
    }

    public int getSegundo() {
        return segundo;
    }

    public int getMinuto() {
        return minuto;
    }

    public int getHora() {
        return hora;
    }

    public int getDia() {
        return dia;
    }

    public int getMes() {
        return mes;
    }

    public long getAno() {
        return ano;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(segundo, minuto, hora, dia, mes, ano);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof DataUTC)) return false;
        DataUTC outro = (DataUTC) obj;
        return this.segundo == outro.segundo && this.minuto == outro.minuto && this.hora == outro.hora
                && this.dia == outro.dia && this.mes == outro.mes && this.ano == outro.ano;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(DataUTC other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        if (this.ano != other.ano) return this.ano > other.ano ? 1 : -1;
        if (this.mes != other.mes) return this.mes > other.mes ? 1 : -1;
        if (this.dia != other.dia) return this.dia > other.dia ? 1 : -1;
        if (this.hora != other.hora) return this.hora > other.hora ? 1 : -1;
        if (this.minuto != other.minuto) return this.minuto > other.minuto ? 1 : -1;
        if (this.segundo != other.segundo) return this.segundo > other.segundo ? 1 : -1;
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%02d/%02d/%04d %02d:%02d:%02d", dia, mes, ano, hora, minuto, segundo);
    }
}
```

E aqui vai o teste da classe acima:

```java
import static DataUTC.DiaDaSemana.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(-12_005_355_554L, "26/07/1589 03:00:46", QUARTA_FEIRA);
        test( -1_234_567_890L, "18/11/1930 00:28:30", TERCA_FEIRA);
        test(   -777_777_777L, "09/05/1945 22:37:03", QUARTA_FEIRA);
        test(              -1, "31/12/1969 23:59:59", QUARTA_FEIRA);
        test(              0L, "01/01/1970 00:00:00", QUINTA_FEIRA);
        test(              1L, "01/01/1970 00:00:01", QUINTA_FEIRA);
        test(      451551900L, "23/04/1984 07:05:00", SEGUNDA_FEIRA);
        test(    915_148_801L, "01/01/1999 00:00:01", SEXTA_FEIRA);
        test(  1_000_000_000L, "09/09/2001 01:46:40", DOMINGO);
        test(  1_234_567_890L, "13/02/2009 23:31:30", SEXTA_FEIRA);
        test(  4_294_967_295L, "07/02/2106 06:28:15", DOMINGO);
        test(  6_505_355_555L, "23/02/2176 11:12:35", SEXTA_FEIRA);
        test( 15_505_445_554L, "07/05/2461 04:12:34", SABADO);
    }

    public static void test(long timestamp, String esperado, DataUTC.DiaDaSemana diaEsperado) {
        DataUTC data = new DataUTC(timestamp);
        String dataObtida = data.toString();
        long timestampObtido = data.getTimestamp();
        DataUTC.DiaDaSemana diaObtido = data.getDiaDaSemana();
        if (!esperado.equals(dataObtida) || timestamp != data.getTimestamp() || diaEsperado != diaObtido) {
            System.out.println("Falhou para " + timestamp + " -> " + esperado + " " + diaEsperado
                    + ", veio " + dataObtida + " (" + timestampObtido + ") " + diaObtido);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Funcionou para " + timestamp + " -> " + esperado + " " + diaEsperado + ".");
        }
    }
}
```

E aqui vai o resultado do teste:

```
Funcionou para -12005355554 -> 26/07/1589 03:00:46 QUARTA_FEIRA.
Funcionou para -1234567890 -> 18/11/1930 00:28:30 TERCA_FEIRA.
Funcionou para -777777777 -> 09/05/1945 22:37:03 QUARTA_FEIRA.
Funcionou para -1 -> 31/12/1969 23:59:59 QUARTA_FEIRA.
Funcionou para 0 -> 01/01/1970 00:00:00 QUINTA_FEIRA.
Funcionou para 1 -> 01/01/1970 00:00:01 QUINTA_FEIRA.
Funcionou para 451551900 -> 23/04/1984 07:05:00 SEGUNDA_FEIRA.
Funcionou para 915148801 -> 01/01/1999 00:00:01 SEXTA_FEIRA.
Funcionou para 1000000000 -> 09/09/2001 01:46:40 DOMINGO.
Funcionou para 1234567890 -> 13/02/2009 23:31:30 SEXTA_FEIRA.
Funcionou para 4294967295 -> 07/02/2106 06:28:15 DOMINGO.
Funcionou para 6505355555 -> 23/02/2176 11:12:35 SEXTA_FEIRA.
Funcionou para 15505445554 -> 07/05/2461 04:12:34 SABADO.
```

## Representações no banco de dados e linguagens de programação

Os bancos de dados representam datas de diversas formas diferentes, não necessariamente com o *timestamp do unix*.

- Tal como mencionado acima, [o `TIMESTAMP` do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) armazena uma *timestamp do unix* de 32 bits com sinal, e por isso está susceptível ao bug do ano 2038.
  O formato `DATETIME` do MySQL remedia o problema do formato `TIMESTAMP` do mesmo, [podendo armazenar de 01/01/1000 até 31/12/9999](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html). Nenhum destes formatos armazena frações de segundo, e portanto para armazená-los, você terá que colocá-los em alguma coluna numérica para tal finalidade.
- No MariaDB (que para quem não sabe, é um fork do MySQL), os tipos [`TIMESTAMP`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/timestamp/) e [`DATETIME`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/datetime/) funcionam de forma parecida com a do MySQL (inclusive com o bug do ano 2038 para o `TIMESTAMP`). Porém, diferentemente do MySQL, o MariaDB aceita frações de segundo com uma precisão máxima de microsegundos.
- [No Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/articles/sql/introducao-tipo-de-dado-timestamp-1505073-ptb.html), o tipo `TIMESTAMP` é capaz de armazenar datas de 4712 antes de Cristo até o ano 9999, com uma precisão que pode ser definida de 1 segundo até 1 nanosegundo (bilionésimos de segundo). incluindo (ou não) informação referente a fuso horário. O tipo `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` armazena também o fuso horário.
- [No PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html), o tipo `TIMESTAMP` (ou `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`), com 8 bytes, é capaz de armazenar datas de 4713 antes de Cristo até o ano 294276, com precisão de microsegundos (milionésimos de segundo). É possível também reduzir-se a precisão para aumentar-se o intervalo aceito. Há também o tipo `TIMESTAMPTZ` (ou `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`) que também armazena o fuso horário.
- No SQL Server, [o tipo `TIMESTAMP` é uma equivalência *deprecated* para o tipo `ROWVERSION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx), que na verdade constitui-se de um campo que é alterado automaticamente sempre que um registro é alterado e armazena um valor garantidamente único, não tendo relação com datas. [No SQL Server, o tipo `DATETIME` utiliza 8 bytes para armazenar datas de 01/01/1753 até 31/12/9999, com precisão de cerca de 3 milisegundos.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) Também há o tipo [`SMALLDATETIME` que utiliza 4 bytes para armazenar datas de 01/01/1900 até 06/06/2079 com precisão de 1 minuto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx), o tipo [`DATETIME2`, que armazena qualquer data e hora representável com um ano de quatro dígitos com uma precisão de décimos de milionésimos de segundo.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx) e um tipo [`DATETIMEOFFSET` que armazena também o fuso horário](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx).
- [No Firebird](http://www.arquivodecodigos.net/dicas/firebird-aprenda-a-usar-os-tipos-de-dados-date-time-e-timestamp-do-firebird-3252.html), o tipo `TIMESTAMP` utiliza 4 bytes para armazenar a data e 4 para armazenar a hora, totalizando 8 bytes. A data pode variar de 01/01/0001 até 31/12/9999 e a hora tem precisão de décimos de milésimos de segundos.
- A maioria das linguagens de programação modernas usam o *timestamp do unix*. No C, que é ou usado como base para as demais linguagens ou então imitado por estas, o tipo `time_t` não é definido com nenhum tamanho ou formato fixo. Em sistemas mais antigos, ele era representado como um inteiro de 32 bits com sinal, sendo então susceptível ao bug do ano 2038. Em sistemas modernos, ele frequentemente é implementado como um inteiro de 64 bits com sinal. ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#Representing_the_number))

## Outros formatos:

> Existem outros sabores de timestamp?

- O Excel (tal como o [ctgPi mencionou na resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70486/132)) usa como base o número de dias desde 01/01/1900, tendo as horas como parte fracionária. Curiosamente, este formato advém do paleozóico Lotus 1-2-3, que tinha um bug que fazia o ano de 1900 ser considerado bissexto e este bug existe no Excel até hoje [(fonte)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214058/en-us). Corrigindo-se o bug, a data base dele passa a ser 31/12/1899. A implementação deste formato, seria parecida com a implementação acima dada para o *timestamp do unix*, apenas usando como base o ano de 1900 ao invés de 1970, trabalhando-se com números de ponto flutuante ao invés de inteiros, multiplicando-se/dividindo-se o *timestamp* por 86400 e dando-se um jeitinho no dia (que não existiu) 29 de fevereiro de 1900.
- Existe uma variante do *timestamp do unix* que consiste na contagem de milisegundos desde 01/01/1970 ao invés do número de segundos. Basta multiplicar/dividir o *timestamp* por 1000 e somar os milisegundos.
- Outro exemplo notável é o [antigo formato de data/hora do MS-DOS](http://proger.i-forge.net/MS-DOS_date_and_time_format/OFz), que também foi utilizado pelo formato ZIP. Este formato consistia do armazenamento da data em 2 bytes e a hora em outros 2 bytes:

  - Para a data, os 7 primeiros bits representavam o ano desde 1980 (e portanto só podia representar anos de 1980 até 2107), os próximos 4 bits representavam o mês e os últimos 5 bits representavam o dia.
  - O horário, era armazenado com 5 bits para a hora, 6 bits para o minuto e 5 bits para o segundo dividido por dois. Este detalhe dos segundos, fazia com que a precisão/resolução dele fosse de 2 segundos, sendo o número de segundos resultantes sempre par, pois ele era armazenado como um número de 0 a 29 a ser multiplicado por 2, o que causava vários problemas em programas que esperavam que o número do segundo não tivesse este comportamento.

## E o ISO?

Há um [formato ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) de representação de datas (na verdade um conjunto de formatos). Isso não tem a ver com o *timestamp do unix*, é apenas uma forma universal de representar datas, vez que diferentes países a representam de forma diferente, o que pode gerar confusão. Por exemplo, no Brasil costuma-se usar `DD/MM/YYYY`, enquanto que nos EUA usa-se `MM/DD/YYYY`, na Armênia usa-se `DD.MM.YYYY`, no Japão usa-se `YYYY年MM月DD日`. [(fonte)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country)

O formato ISO 8601 consiste em um dos seguintes:

- Ano no formato `YYYY`.
- Ano e mês no formato `YYYY-MM`.
- Ano, mês e dia no formato `YYYY-MM-DD`.
- Ano, mês, dia, horas, minutos e fuso horário no formato `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTZD`.
- Ano, mês, dia, horas, minutos, segundos e fuso horário no formato `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD`.
- Ano, mês, dia, horas, minutos, segundos, frações de segundos e fuso horário no formato `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD`.

Aonde:

- `YYYY` é o ano com quatro dígitos.
- `MM` é o mês com dois dígitos.
- `DD` é o dia com dois dígitos.
- `hh` é a hora com dois dígitos.
- `mm` são os minutos com dois dígitos.
- `ss` são os segundos com dois dígitos.
- `s` são as frações de segundos, com um ou mais dígitos.
- `TZD` é o fuso horário.
- Os caracteres `-`, `:`, `T` e `.` são escritos literalmente.

O fuso horário pode ter o formato `+hh:mm` ou `-hh:mm` para especificar um deslocamento em relação ao UTC, ou pode ser representado como `Z` para expressar o próprio UTC.

Desta forma, estas são algumas datas e horas expressas no ISO 8601:

- 2012
- 2012-04
- 2012-04-21
- 2012-04-21T12:21Z
- 2012-04-21T12:21+03:00
- 2012-04-21T12:21:44-10:30
- 2012-04-21T12:21:44.6-04:00
- 2012-04-21T12:21:44.67893-09:20
- 2012-04-21T12:21:44.67893Z

---

Mais detalhes sobre o calendário gregoriano fornecido pelo PPK [(obrigado ao ctgPi pelo comentário)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70473/como-%c3%a9-feito-o-calculo-do-timestamp/70604#comment144713_70604). Eis o link: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/04/making_time_saf.html

Comment: +1, mas acho que cabe mencionar que a data crítica pra transição ao calendário gregoriano depende da parte do mundo à qual a sua data se refere — pense e.g. no caso da Revolução Russa. Se você quiser falar mais ainda de tempo, o [PPK](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/04/making_time_saf.html) tem um artigo mais bolado ainda sobre tempos e datas.

Comment: Excelente resposta +1 :D

Comment: uau! estou até sem folego.

Answer (score 14):

Como o Earendul observou, o `timestamp` do UNIX são os segundos decorridos desde a meia-noite de 1º de janeiro de 1970 UTC. Por exemplo, na minha máquina,

```
landingpad:~ fmoreira$ date -r 0
Wed Dec 31 21:00:00 BRT 1969
```

Note que se você está fazendo contas com tempo para experimentos de física ou astronomia, o UNIX ignora [segundos bissextos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segundo_bissexto).

O Excel, por outro lado, mede datas e horas em número inteiro de dias desde 1º de janeiro de *1900* (horas, minutos e segundos são representados como frações de dia); você pode verificar isso formatando uma coluna de números comuns como data.

Como os SGBDs representam `TIMESTAMP` (na realidade existem dois tipos, o `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` e o `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`) é um detalhe de implementação, e portanto é difícil responder a sua pergunta sem saber exatamente qual SGBD você tem em mente (apesar da maioria simplesmente guardar uma data/hora com precisão de microsegundo), mas duas pegadinhas importantes são:

- O `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` não é o instante atual, mas o instante em que a transação atual se iniciou (eles são iguais se você estiver com AUTOCOMMIT ligado); isso é útil se você pretende usar `TIMESTAMP`s como chaves de alguma tabela — mesmo em comandos diferentes, `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` sempre vai ter o mesmo valor dentro da mesma transação.
- No MySQL, o `TIMESTAMP` tem um “*feature*” no qual atualizações à linha da tabela automaticamente atualizam o timestamp daquela linha, mesmo que você não tenha mexido naquela coluna específica; o en.SO tem [uma solução para este problema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8131725/timestamp-without-change-on-update).
- Também no MySQL, o `TIMESTAMP` sofre do [bug do ano 2038](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2012620/540552), como bem observou o Victor Stafusa; o `DATETIME` só vai dar problema no ano 10000.

Comment: Cuidado com o [bug do ano 2038](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2012620/540552) ao usar `TIMESTAMP` no MySQL. Prefira usar `DATETIME`.

Comment: Obrigado; foi por causa desses “_easter eggs_” que eu parei de usar o MySQL. Esse problema é específico só a ele? `TIMESTAMP` é ANSI SQL, ao contrário de `DATETIME`; se for só o MySQL com o problema do 2k38, acho importante mencionar que é só ele que é bichado.