# Converter data e hora para valor numérico em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, data, timestamp

Eu vi no [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) as datas serem tratadas como valores numéricos.

Por exemplo, a data `2016-05-03T10:00:00` é igual ao valor numérico `1462280400000`.

Gostaria de entender como funciona isso, e qual função pode converter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isso provavelmente é [*timestamp*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_temporal) que é a quantidade de segundos desde uma data específica (`1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC`), portanto ela não pode representar qualquer data. Se é isso que deseja aí é só usar a função [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

```js
data = new Date(2016, 04, 03, 10, 30);
console.log(data.getTime());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Typing/GetNumberFromDate.js).

Answer (score 2):

Esse valor numérico (`1462280400000`) é o [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052), que é a quantidade de tempo que se passou desde o [*Unix Epoch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (sendo que o *Unix Epoch* corresponde a 1 de janeiro de 1970, à meia-noite, [em UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)).

O mais comum é ver este valor em segundos ou milissegundos (dependendo da linguagem ou API, e algumas podem ter mais precisão, como microssegundos ou até mesmo nanossegundos, [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/431085/112052) alguns exemplos). No caso, o valor `1462280400000` está em milissegundos, e no JavaScript você pode passá-lo diretamente para o construtor de `Date`:

```js
// converter o timestamp para uma data
let data = new Date(1462280400000);
console.log(data);
```

O oposto (obter o timestamp correspondente à data) pode ser obtido pelo [método `getTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime):

```js
// a partir de uma data, obter o timestamp
let data = new Date(2016, 4, 3, 10, 0);
console.log(data.getTime());

// também pode usar a string diretamente
data = new Date('2016-05-03T10:00:00');
console.log(data.getTime());
```

Repare que no primeiro caso, o mês é 4, pois no JavaScript [os meses são indexados em zero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405998/112052) (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc).

Já no segundo caso eu passei diretamente a string `'2016-05-03T10:00:00'`, que está no formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (que o construtor de `Date` aceita normalmente), e neste caso o mês é `05` mesmo (quando é uma string, os meses têm os valores corretos: janeiro é 1, fevereiro é 2, etc - confuso, mas é assim mesmo).

---

Mas há um detalhe nos códigos acima: os resultados podem variar dependendo do timezone (fuso horário) do *browser* - que geralmente usa o que está configurado no sistema operacional (no caso do Node.js, [é possível configurá-lo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46107140)). Ou seja, no primeiro código (`new Date(1462280400000)`), a data que será impressa por `console.log` pode não ser 3 de maio de 2016 às 10:00, e no segundo caso o timestamp retornado por `getTime()` pode não ser `1462280400000`.

Isso acontece porque o timestamp representa um único instante, um ponto na linha do tempo. Só que esse mesmo instante corresponde a uma data e/ou hora diferentes, dependendo do timezone. Por exemplo, o timestamp `1462280400000` corresponde a:

- 3 de maio de 2016 às 10:00 no Horário de Brasília
- 3 de maio de 2016 às **15**:00 em Berlim
- **4** de maio de 2016 às 01:00 na Nova Zelândia

**Todas as datas e horas acima correspondem ao timestamp `1462280400000`** - todas elas correspondem ao mesmo instante, ao mesmo ponto na linha do tempo (no mesmo momento em que é 3 de maio às 10h em São Paulo, na Nova Zelândia já é dia 4 à uma da manhã).

Então dependendo do timezone que estiver configurado, os valores retornados podem ser completamente diferentes. No primeiro caso, ao passar o timestamp para o construtor de `Date`, a data exibida por `console.log` será de acordo com este timezone.

Já no segundo caso (passando os valores de data e hora, ou a string), o construtor vai considerar o instante correspondente a 3 de maio de 2016, às 10h, no timezone do browser (que por sua vez pode corresponder a um valor de timestamp diferente de `1462280400000`, já que em cada parte do mundo esta data e hora ocorreram em momentos diferentes).

*Se não me engano o Chrome pega o fuso que está configurado no sistema operacional, tente alterá-lo e rodar os códigos acima no console do browser para ver a diferença.*

---

### Moment.js

Infelizmente o JavaScript está limitado ao timezone do browser, e não há como especificar algum outro à sua escolha. Mas se quiser ser mais específico, pode usar o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), juntamente com o [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/):

```js
// obter data a partir do timestamp, usando um timezone específico
let data = moment.tz(1462280400000, "America/Sao_Paulo");
console.log(data.format()); // 2016-05-03T10:00:00-03:00

// o mesmo timestamp, mas em outro timezone
data = moment.tz(1462280400000, "Europe/Berlin");
console.log(data.format()); // 2016-05-03T15:00:00+02:00

//-----------------------------------------------------
// uma data e hora, em um timezone específico
data = moment.tz("2016-05-03T10:00:00", "America/Sao_Paulo");
console.log(data.valueOf()); // obter o timestamp: 1462280400000

// a mesma data e hora, mas em outro timezone
data = moment.tz("2016-05-03T10:00:00", "Europe/Berlin");
console.log(data.valueOf()); // timestamp diferente do valor acima: 1462262400000
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Dessa forma, você pode dizer explicitamente que a data e hora referem-se a um timezone específico, independente do que estiver configurado no browser. No exemplo acima usei `America/Sao_Paulo`, que corresponde ao Horário de Brasília, e em seguida usei `Europe/Berlin`, que corresponde ao fuso horário da Alemanha.

Nos 2 primeiros casos, usei o mesmo timestamp, mas em timezones diferentes, e o resultado foi a data e hora correspondente em cada um destes fusos (repare que o horário é diferente, pois neste instante, quando era 10h em São Paulo, em Berlim já era 15h).

Já nos 2 últimos casos, os valores dos timestamps são diferentes, pois "3 de maio de 2016 às 10h" ocorreu em instantes diferentes em cada um destes timezones.

Esses nomes de timezones no formato `Continente/Região` são definidos pelo [Time Zone Database da IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). Se quiser ver todos os timezones disponíveis, use [`moment.tz.names()`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/getting-zone-names/) e escolha o que for mais adequado para o seu caso.

---

Por fim, vale sempre lembrar que a transformação de uma data e hora em um timestamp - e vice-versa - sempre envole algum timezone. Mesmo se este não estiver explícito, tem algum sendo usado internamente. Não tem "mágica".