# O que o número retornado por System.currentTimeMillis representa?

Tags: java, data, datetime, timestamp

Fui ler a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--), disponibilizada pela IDE e me deparei com isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É dito que o método `System.currentTimeMillis` retorna:

> *the difference, measured in milliseconds, between the current time and midnight, January 1, 1970 UTC.*

Pensei que esse método representava o tempo a partir do boot atual. Se ele não representa, o que essa data citada tem de especial? Esse número é padrão para todos os computadores?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

O método [`System.currentTimeMillis`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis--) retorna o valor do [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) em milissegundos (também conhecido como "milésimos de segundo"). Mas vamos por partes.

---

Conforme você viu na documentação, o retorno é descrito como "*a diferença, em milissegundos, entre a data/hora atual e 1 de janeiro de 1970, à meia-noite, em UTC*".

Esta data (1 de janeiro de 1970, à meia-noite, [**em UTC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), que você também pode ver por aí escrita no [formato ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), ou seja, `1970-01-01T00:00Z`) é chamada de [*Unix Epoch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), e podemos considerá-la - para simplificar - como o "instante zero".

O que `System.currentTimeMillis` retorna é um **número** (no caso, um `long`) que representa a quantidade de milissegundos que se passou desde este instante.

Por exemplo, rodando agora, eu obtive o valor `1579182398676` (mais de 1 trilhão e 579 bilhões de milissegundos). É importante notar que este valor é o mesmo em todo o mundo - qualquer computador, em qualquer lugar do mundo, que chamasse este método no mesmo instante que eu obteria o mesmo resultado (assumindo que o relógio do computador não está com problemas, etc).

Ou seja, o timestamp representa um instante único, um ponto na linha do tempo. O detalhe é que em cada parte do mundo (em cada fuso horário), esse mesmo valor pode representar uma data e hora diferentes. Por exemplo, o timestamp `1579182398676` corresponde a:

- 16 de janeiro de 2020, às 13:46:38.676 em Londres
- 16 de janeiro de 2020, às **10**:46:38.676 em São Paulo
- **17** de janeiro de 2020, às **02**:46:38.676 em Auckland (Nova Zelândia)
- e em cada parte do mundo, poderá ser uma data e/ou hora diferentes

Todas as datas e horas acima correspondem ao mesmo timestamp (`1579182398676`) - ao mesmo instante.

---

Quanto a ser padronizado, depende muito do que significa "padronizado".

`System.currentTimeMillis` retorna este valor em milissegundos, mas há outras linguagens/API's que trabalham com este valor em segundos, como é o caso da [função `time`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) do PHP, por exemplo. Já o [módulo `datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) do Python possui o [método `datetime.timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp), que também retorna o valor em segundos, mas diferente do PHP, ele retorna um `float` que [também possui as frações de segundo](https://ideone.com/Cxizf6).

No próprio Java, a partir do JDK 8, temos a [API `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html), que possui precisão de nanossegundos (9 casas decimais na fração de segundos), o que acarreta em perda de precisão ao converter os tipos desta API para [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) ou [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) (veja [no início desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/370367/112052) alguns detalhes sobre isso). O detalhe é que métodos como [`Instant.now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now--) usam "o melhor relógio disponível no sistema", que pode ou não ter precisão de nanossegundos (portanto, a quantidade de casas decimais retornadas depende do ambiente no qual o código roda).

Sem contar que a classe [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) pode trabalhar tanto com o valor em milissegundos (com os métodos [`ofEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-) e [`toEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--)) quando em segundos (com [`ofEpochSecond`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-) e [`getEpochSecond`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#getEpochSecond--)), o que é bem raro, já que a maioria das linguagens e API's só trabalha com uma dessas opções.

Ou seja, mesmo que muitas linguagens usem o conceito do timestamp, deve-se levar em conta essas diferenças. Podemos considerar que é padronizado porque elas usam a mesma ideia, ou que não é padronizado porque cada uma pode retornar o valor com uma precisão diferente?

Outro detalhe é que o *Unix Epoch* não é o único valor utilizado como o "instante zero". No .NET, por exemplo, um [`DateTime`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.8) usa a quantidade de "ticks" desde 1 de janeiro do ano 1 (não é 1901 nem 2001, é o ano 1 mesmo), à meia-noite, em UTC (sendo que um "tick" é igual a 100 nanossegundos). Além disso, [há vários outros *epochs* usados na computação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing).