# SP2-0552: Variável de Bind "19" não declarada

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Estou utilizando o Oracle SQL Developer para terminar um projeto, quando fui popular o banco, o software acusou um erro na seguinte linha:

```
INSERT INTO musica (cod_musica, data_composicao, titulo, duracao)
VALUES (11111, '1993/01/01', 'Fênis', '22/12/2016 00:15:19 123');
```

`data_composicao` está como `DATE` e `duracao` está como `TIMESTAMP`, mesmo quando tiro os `''` não consigo fazer funcionar, desde já agradeço pela atenção.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que a fração dos segundos que você está utilizando separada, está errada, sendo o correto separar com ponto;

A máscara para a fração dos segundos é definida pelo [`FF`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1029.htm#OLADM780);

O valor salvo no campo `duracao`, tem o formato de dia/mes/ano, portanto, a máscara deve seguir este formado (dd/mm/yyyy);

Desta forma, seu `insert` irá ficar assim:

```
INSERT INTO musica (cod_musica, data_composicao, titulo, duracao)
VALUES (11111, TO_DATE('1993/01/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 'Fênis', TO_TIMESTAMP('22/12/2016 00:15:19.123', 'dd/mm/yyyy HH24:MI:SS.FF3'));
```

[Neste post](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70473/como-%C3%A9-feito-o-c%C3%A1lculo-do-timestamp), tem uma bela resposta sobre o [`TIMESTAMP`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/articles/sql/introducao-tipo-de-dado-timestamp-1505073-ptb.html).

[Documentação oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2118.htm#OLADM696)