# O que está acontecendo de errado? BD + Laravel

Tags: php, html5, banco-de-dados, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estou com um formulário em blade pegando os valores do banco de dados. Nele tenho um campo `date` não obrigatório de ser preenchido. Quando cadastro uma data vazia a tela de resultados exibe a data `"01/01/1970"`. Como faço pra mudar esse comportamento? Gostaria que aparecesse vazio quando a variável estivesse vazia.

```
<th><a href="{{ URL::to('contas?sort=datapagamento') }}">Data de Pagamento</a></th>
<td>{{ date("d/m/Y", strtotime($conta->datapagamento)) }}</td>
```

Comment: [Datas frequentemente são representadas como o número de segundos desde 01/01/1970](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/132). Assim sendo, como você não tem nenhuma data, um zero foi obtido de alguma forma e esse zero acabou virando 01/01/1970.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode usar o `if` na `blade`.

Fazendo assim você verifica se o campo está preenchido.
Ele está colocando essa data por causa da função `date()` do PHP. Como não tem nada nenhuma, ele coloca essa.

```
<th>
    <a href="{{ URL::to('contas?sort=datapagamento') }}">
       Data de Pagamento
    </a>
</th>

<td>
    @if($conta->datapagamento)
        {{ date("d/m/Y", strtotime($conta->datapagamento)) }}
    @else
       Sem Data
    @endif
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando aparece a data 01/01/1970 é bem provável que o dado está chegando como YYYY-MM-DD e você está mandando ele mostrar d/m/Y e ocorre este erro.

Uma boa forma de sanar isso é fazendo um helper

```
<?php

namespace App\Domains\Helpers;

use DateTime;

class DataHelper
{
    const FORMATO_BR = 'd/m/Y';
    const FORMATO_US = 'Y-m-d';

    public static function toBR($data)
    {
        if ($data === '0000-00-00') {
            return '00/00/0000';
        }
        return DateTime::createFromFormat(self::FORMATO_US, $data)->format(self::FORMATO_BR);
    }

    public static function toUS($data)
    {
        if ($data === '00/00/0000') {
            return '0000-00-00';
        }
        return DateTime::createFromFormat(self::FORMATO_BR, $data)->format(self::FORMATO_US);
    }
}
```