# Long ou Date em JSON

Tags: java, json, web-service, data, timestamp

Aplicações, uma servidora e várias clientes, `POST` e `GET` para o servidor trocam objetos `JSON`.

Uma das variáveis que tramita junto com o `JSON` é a `datahora atual`, vejo diferentes `Strings` para representar as datas, como:

```
"\"\\/Date(1335205592410)\\/\""         .NET JavaScriptSerializer
"\"\\/Date(1335205592410-0500)\\/\""    .NET DataContractJsonSerializer
"2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z"              JavaScript built-in JSON object
"2012-04-21T18:25:43-05:00"             ISO 8601
```

Ou até mesmo o erro retornado do servidor, traz alguns exemplos de *parsers* para essas datas:

```
(error: Failed to parse Date value 'Jun 7, 2017 08:44:51 AM': Can not parse date "Jun 7, 2017 11:44:51 AM": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Pesquisei, e pouco se fala sobre representar essa data em um `long`, enviando e apenas criando um `Date` no servidor ou até mesmo salvando como `long` no banco, pelo menos assim me parece mais simples e evitaria esses problemas de leitura da data.

Sei que é possível fazer isso, mas fiquei curioso pelas poucas implementações, ou quase nenhuma que achei. Desta forma, utilizando o `long`, estaria errado, ou então, seria algum tipo de "bad practice"?

Comment: Cara, em minha opinião não é errado utilizar o long, pois o long é o timeInMillis, ou seja, a data atual em milisegundos, enviando a informação desta forma, você não terá essas divergências de formato como no .net, javascript e etc..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depende do que você precisa.

O número gigante, representando por um `long`, é um [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052). Ele representa um único instante, um ponto na linha do tempo, que corresponde à quantidade de milissegundos desde o [*Unix Epoch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (cujo valor é 01/01/1970, à meia-noite em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)).

O número `1335205592410`, por exemplo, representa o instante ocorrido 1335205592410ms depois do *Unix Epoch*. O detalhe é que esse mesmo valor corresponde a uma data e hora diferente, dependendo do *timezone* (fuso-horário). Alguns exemplos:

- 23 de abril de 2012 às 15:26:32.410 em São Paulo
- 24 de abril de 2012 às 03:26:32.410 em Tóquio
- 23 de abril de 2012 às 18:26:32.410 em UTC

Ou seja, o **mesmo** valor de timestamp (`1335205592410`) corresponde a todas as datas e horas acima. Em São Paulo, esse timestamp corresponde ao dia 23 às 15h, e em Tóquio, ao dia 24 às 3 da manhã. Mas o **instante** é o mesmo, por isso o valor do timestamp é o mesmo para ambos.

Dito isso, o timestamp é útil para quando você precisar saber o instante exato em que algo aconteceu, independente de fusos-horários. Caso você precise "traduzir" o timestamp para uma data e hora, basta usar as APIs do Java para esta transformação.

### Java >= 8

A partir do Java 8 você pode usar a API [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), muito mais moderna e que corrige os [vários problemas da API anterior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442) (`Date` e `Calendar`).

Para converter o timestamp para uma data e hora, primeiro usamos um [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), que representa um instante específico (um ponto na linha do tempo), ou seja, exatamente o mesmo conceito de um timestamp.

Em seguida, convertemos este `Instant` para um [`java.time.ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), que representa uma data e hora em um *timezone* específico. Lembre-se que o mesmo timestamp corresponde a uma data e hora diferentes em cada *timezone*, então temos que escolher um e passar para a classe [`java.time.ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html):

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(1335205592410L);
// converte para o timezone America/Sao_Paulo
ZonedDateTime dataHoraSp = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
System.out.println(dataHoraSp);
```

A saída é:

> 2012-04-23T15:26:32.410-03:00[America/Sao_Paulo]

O timezone escolhido foi `America/Sao_Paulo`, que está no formato da [IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) (sempre com este formato `Continente/Região`). Você pode verificar todos os timezones disponíveis usando o método [`ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#getAvailableZoneIds--). E se quiser usar o timezone *default* que estiver configurado na JVM, basta usar [`ZoneId.systemDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--) em vez de [`ZoneId.of(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-).

A grande vantagem de usar os timezones da IANA é que eles possuem todo o histórico de alterações no horário local de cada região. Por isso, ajustes como horário de verão são feitos automaticamente, e o `ZonedDateTime` terá os valores corretos de data e hora.

Para mais detalhes sobre esta API, sugiro o [tutorial da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) e [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052). Um detalhe é que, caso o banco que você está usando tenha um driver compatível com o **JDBC 4.2**, é possível trabalhar diretamente com o `Instant`, usando os métodos `setObject` da classe [`java.sql.PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) e `getObject` da classe [`java.sql.ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

```
PreparedStatement ps = ...
// seta o java.time.Instant
ps.setObject(1, datetime.toInstant());

// obter o Instant do banco
ResultSet rs = ...
Instant instant = rs.getObject(1, Instant.class);
// converter o instant para o timezone
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
```

---

### Java <= 7

No Java <= 7, basta converter o timestamp para [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). Mas como esta classe não possui informação sobre o timezone, o melhor jeito de obter a data e hora em um formato específico é usando um [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) e setando um [`java.util.TimeZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html) nele:

```
// cria Date a partir do timestamp
Date date = new Date(1335205592410L);
// gerar String que corresponde à data e hora em um timezone
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
System.out.println(sdf.format(date)); // 2012-04-23T15:26:32.410-03:00
```

O resultado será uma `String` com a data e hora correspondentes ao timestamp, no timezone especificado no `SimpleDateFormat`:

> 2012-04-23T15:26:32.410-03:00

Outra opção é criar um [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), caso deseje obter os campos de data e hora individualmente, por exemplo:

```
// ou crie um Calendar, se quiser obter os campos de data e hora individualmente
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
calendar.setTimeInMillis(1335205592410L); // usar o valor do timestamp
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)); // 15
System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); // 23
```

Outra alternativa é usar o [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), um excelente *backport* do `java.time`, que funciona no JDK 6 e 7. As classes possuem os mesmos nomes e funcionalidades do `java.time`, a diferença é que o nome do pacote é `org.threeten.bp`.

---

## Sempre devo usar o timestamp?

Depende. Que tipo de informação você vai guardar?

Se quiser saber exatamente em que instante algo ocorreu, independente do fuso horário, o timestamp é a melhor opção.

Mas e se você só quer gravar a data de nascimento para um cadastro simples? Ou seja, só precisa do dia, mês e ano (e não precisa das horas, nem do fuso-horário). Neste caso o timestamp é um exagero (pois possui mais informação do que você precisa), e além disso pode causar erros inesperados.

Lembre-se - novamente - que o mesmo valor de timestamp pode resultar em uma data e hora diferente, dependendo do timezone escolhido. Se você simplesmente criar um `java.util.Date`, por exemplo, e imprimir, poderá ter um resultado diferente a cada execução:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
// cria Date a partir do timestamp
Date date = new Date(1335205592410L);
System.out.println(date.getTime() + "=" + date);

// mudar o timezone default
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo"));
System.out.println(date.getTime() + "=" + date);
```

Repare que imprimi o valor de `date.getTime()` (que retorna o valor do timestamp), e em seguida o próprio `date`, que internamente chamará o seu método `toString()`. A saída é:

> 1335205592410=Mon Apr 23 15:26:32 BRT 2012
>   1335205592410=Tue Apr 24 03:26:32 JST 2012

Repare que, apesar do timestamp não ter mudado, a data e hora mudaram. Isso acontece porque `Date`, ao ser impresso, usa o timezone *default* da JVM para converter o timestamp para uma data e hora. E quando eu mudei o timezone *default* usando [`TimeZone.setDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-), o retorno de `toString()` também muda. O valor do timestamp não muda, mas o valor da data e hora que é impresso sim. E isso vale também para `SimpleDateFormat`, que quando criado, usa o timezone *default* que estiver setado no momento, então todas as datas sendo formatadas (e todas as strings sendo *parseadas*) serão afetadas também (isso pode ser evitado se você setar o timezone, usando `setTimeZone` no `SimpleDateFormat`, como já explicado anteriormente).

O problema é que qualquer aplicação pode chamar `TimeZone.setDefault` e afetar todas as outras aplicações que estão rodando na mesma JVM. E de repente você começa a ver valores de `Date` inesperados, embora o seu valor (o timestamp) não tenha mudado.

Infelizmente, antes do Java 8 não havia (usando somente a API nativa) uma forma confiável de guardar apenas uma data (somente dia, mês e ano, sem horas nem timezone). Mesmo a classe `java.sql.Date`, que foi feita para representar este conceito, internamente possui um timestamp e sofre do mesmo problema (seu valor ao ser impressa muda conforme o timezone *default* da JVM).

---

No Java >= 8 é possível usar a classe [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), que representa somente um dia, mês e ano, sem qualquer noção de horários ou timezones. Neste caso, não há qualquer relação com timestamps, pois tendo somente a data, sem saber o horário e o timezone, não há como ter o timestamp correspondente.

A vantagem é que os valores impressos são sempre os mesmos, não importando qual o timezone *default*:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Sao_Paulo"));
// 23 de abril de 2012
LocalDate dt = LocalDate.of(2012, 4, 23);
System.out.println(dt);

// mudar o timezone default
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tokyo"));
System.out.println(dt);
```

Como `LocalDate` não sofre interferência do timezone, a saída é:

> 2012-04-23
>   2012-04-23

E da mesma forma que `Instant`, um `LocalDate` também pode ser utilizado diretamente, caso o banco de dados já tenha um driver compatível com JDBC 4.2. Consulte a respectiva documentação do seu banco de dados para saber se é possível usar estas classes.

---

### Sobre os formatos indicados

Primeiro sobre esses dois:

```
/Date(1335205592410)/ 
/Date(1335205592410-0500)/
```

Esse é, na minha opinião, um dos piores e mais confusos formatos já criados. Ambos possuem o valor do timestamp, e o segundo ainda tem um [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset), que é a diferença com relação a UTC (`-0500`, que significa "5 horas antes de UTC"). Provavelmente deve servir para converter o timestamp para uma data e hora no referido offset.

Apenas como curiosidade, é possível fazer o parsing com o `java.time`:

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoField;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;


DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // parte inicial
    .appendLiteral("/Date(")
    // para o timestamp, usa-se o InstantSeconds e os milissegundos
    .appendValue(ChronoField.INSTANT_SECONDS)
    .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 3)
    // offset opcional (colchetes indicam que o campo é opcional)
    .appendPattern("[XX]")
    // se não tiver offset, assume-se que é zero (UTC)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.OFFSET_SECONDS, 0)
    // parte final, e cria o DateTimeFormatter
    .appendLiteral(")/").toFormatter();
OffsetDateTime odt1 = OffsetDateTime.parse("/Date(1335205592410)/", parser);
System.out.println(odt1); // 2012-04-23T18:26:32.410Z
OffsetDateTime odt2 = OffsetDateTime.parse("/Date(1335205592410-0500)/", parser);
System.out.println(odt2); // 2012-04-23T13:26:32.410-05:00
```

Escolhi [`java.time.OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), pois representa uma data e hora em um offset específico (que no primeiro caso é zero, o que é o mesmo que dizer que a data/hora está em UTC, e no segundo caso é `-0500`, ou "5 horas antes de UTC"). Mas ambas as datas obtidas correspondem ao mesmo instante (ao mesmo timestamp).

Já esses outros formatos:

```
2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z
2012-04-21T18:25:43-05:00
```

Ambos estão no formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). A primeira está em UTC ([é o que o "Z" no final significa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC))), e a segunda está no offset `-05:00` (5 horas antes de UTC). Repare que o offset pode ser escrito com ou sem dois pontos (`-05:00` ou `-0500`), ou ainda ter somente o valor das horas (`-05`). Mas eu recomendo escrever sempre os minutos também, já que [há países que usam fusos horários de meia hora, e até mesmo de 45 minutos](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html).

Outra vantagem do `java.time` é que ela já suporta o formato ISO 8601 por padrão:

```
OffsetDateTime d1 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z");
System.out.println(d1);
OffsetDateTime d2 = OffsetDateTime.parse("2012-04-21T18:25:43-05:00");
System.out.println(d2);
```

Este código imprime:

> 2012-04-23T18:25:43.511Z
>   2012-04-21T18:25:43-05:00

A vantagem do ISO 8601 é ser mais inteligível para humanos (já que ao usar timestamp, não é tão óbvio saber a qual data e hora ele se refere), além de podermos ter valores "parciais", como `2012-04-23` (apenas a data, sem as horas e o offset), `18:25` (somente as horas), etc.

A diferença é que esses valores "parciais" não podem ser traduzidos para um timestamp. Por exemplo, se eu tiver apenas a data "23 de abril de 2012". Sem um horário e um timezone, não tem como saber o instante exato que esta data representa, e por isso não dá para obter um único valor de timestamp (algumas APIs até fazem esta conversão, mas elas implicitamente escolhem algum valor arbitrário para o horário e timezone, e algumas nem permitem que você configure isso). Mas se você só quer fazer o cadastro da data de nascimento dos seus usuários, sem se preocupar com as horas e o fuso horário, então ter apenas o dia, mês e ano é o suficiente.

Se precisar transmitir datas e horas como strings (apenas estes valores, sem se importar com o timezone), o formato ISO 8601 é uma excelente opção.

Só não confunda strings com datas. Uma data/hora representa um conceito: a ideia de um ponto do calendário, um instante na linha do tempo, de um momento específico do dia. Uma string é apenas uma maneira de representar este conceito na forma de texto. Por exemplo, a data "1 de março de 2000" representa este ponto específico do calendário, mas ela pode ser escrita de várias maneiras:

- 01/03/2000
- March 3<sup>th</sup>, 2000
- 2000-03-01
- etc...

Essas strings são diferentes, mas **todas representam a mesma data**. "Traduzindo" para o Java, é como se eu tivesse:

```
String s1 = "01/03/2000";
String s2 = "March 3th, 2000";
String s3 = "2000-03-01";
LocalDate data = LocalDate.of(2000, 3, 1);
```

Cada `String` tem um valor diferente, mas todas representam a mesma data (o mesmo valor que corresponde ao `LocalDate`). Ou seja, os mesmos valores numéricos do dia, mês e ano, que estão contidos na classe `LocalDate`. Uma data só tem os valores, e quando precisamos vê-los (imprimindo na tela, por exemplo) ou enviá-los (seja em um arquivo, seja na resposta de um serviço em JSON), é preciso transformá-los para uma string em algum formato.

---

Enfim, usar o timestamp (o valor do `long`) não é certo nem errado, tudo depende do que você precisa.

Answer (score 0):

Alguns bancos de dados têm o tipo `datetime With TimeZone`, e com isso ele que faz o gerenciamento do TimeZone, caso você salve em milissegundos nâo será possível por exemplo saber o time zone e nem se está com horario de verão ou não por exemplo. Caso isso não faça diferenca para você, salve em `long`, mas o recomendado é utilizar o `Date`, e para resolver esse problema você deve fazer um converter antes de enviar para o servidor.