# Gerar e formatar datas com Moment no Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, data, momentjs

Estou tentando usar o `Moment` para formatação de datas dessa maneira `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` e gostaria de determinar um período entre as 00:00:00h de ontem e 23:59:59 de hoje. Exemplo: considerando hoje como 25/07/2017, ficaria:

```
dateFrom: 2017-07-24 00:00:00
dateTo:  2017-07-25 23:59:59
```

Como gero essas datas com Moment e forço a formatação em `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss`?

Answer (score 1):

Considerando uma variável "data1" que é um objeto do tipo `Date` já esteja com a data correta em questão, que neste caso é `25/07/2017`, basta fazer o seguinte:

```
// data1 já é um objeto do tipo "Date"
var dt = moment(data1);
// 
console.log(dt.format('YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00'));
console.log(dt.format('YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59'));

// Se "data1" também tiver algum valor de hora setado que quisermos saber
console.log(dt.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Estes horários (meia-noite e 23:59:59) representam respectivamente o início e fim do dia, então basta usar as funções [`startOf`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) e [`endOf`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/), que fazem os devidos ajustes para estes horários, bastando passar como parâmetro a string `'day'`:

```js
let d = moment(); // data atual

// startOf seta o horário para meia-noite e endOf, para 23:59:59
// mas se hoje for o dia em que começa o horário de verão no Brasil, startOf pode
// setar para 01:00 (veja explicação mais abaixo)
console.log(d.startOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
console.log(d.endOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Assim, a data tem seu horário alterado para o início do dia (00:00:00) e o final do dia (23:59:59).

"Forçar" os valores do horário para 00:00:00 ou 23:59:59 (tal como feito na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/225179/112052)) também mostra o mesmo resultado, mas há alguns detalhes a se atentar.

O primeiro é que um [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) do JavaScript (que é o [objeto encapsulado por um `Moment`](https://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/js-date/)) na verdade representa um [*timestamp*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) (a quantidade de milissegundos deste o [*Unix Epoch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) e **sempre** possuirá algum valor de hora setado. Na verdade, o *timestamp* representa um instante único - um ponto na linha do tempo - e corresponde a uma data e hora diferentes, dependendo do fuso horário. Mas o ponto é que sempre há um valor para os campos de hora, e ignorá-los ou sobrescrevê-los artificialmente não é a solução ideal.

---

Outro ponto é que `startOf` e `endOf` sempre ajustam os valores de acordo com o timezone (fuso horário) do browser. O meu browser, por exemplo, está usando o timezone correspondente ao Horário de Brasília, e isso pode ter problemas quando começa o horário de verão. Ex:

```js
// 4 de novembro de 2018 (lembrando que janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc)
let d = moment([2018, 10, 4]);

// 2018-11-04 01:00:00 (se o browser usar o fuso do Horário de Brasília)
console.log(d.startOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Usei a data de 4 de novembro de 2018 (lembrando que em JavaScript os meses começam em zero: janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc). No timezone correspondente ao Horário de Brasília, este é o dia em que começou o horário de verão: à meia-noite do dia 4 os relógios foram adiantados automaticamente para 1 da manhã. Isso quer dizer que, na verdade, os relógios pularam de 23:59 do dia 3 direto para 01:00 do dia 4. Ou seja, o início do dia 04/11/2018, neste timezone, foi 1 da manhã (e não meia-noite).

Portanto, **se você testar o código acima em um browser que segue o Horário de Brasília** (geralmente o browser usa a configuração do sistema operacional, verifique o seu antes de testar), o código acima vai imprimir `2018-11-04 01:00:00`. Se estiver usando algum outro timezone (no qual não há mudança de horário de verão neste dia), o resultado será `2018-11-04 00:00:00`.

Portanto, se você usar a solução de sempre colocar o valor fixo `00:00:00`, pode acabar com um problema nas transições do horário de verão. Alguns podem argumentar que colocar `00:00:00` fixo pode "corrigir" este problema, mas na verdade a regra do horário de verão determina que meia-noite não existe naquele dia, naquele fuso horário. Então é melhor mostrar o horário em que o dia se inicia de fato, em vez de mostrar um horário inválido no timezone onde o usuário se encontra.

---

Para o fim do dia, também não é garantido que sempre seja 23:59:59. Por exemplo, [em Bangladesh, em 19 junho de 2019](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/bangladesh/dhaka?year=2009) o horário de verão começou às 23:00, então os relógios foram adiantados de 22:59:29 diretamente para meia-noite do dia 20. Isso quer dizer que o final do dia 19 não foi às 23:59:59, e sim às 22:59:59.

**Mudando a configuração de fuso horário do sistema operacional para "Dhaka, Bangladesh"**, o código abaixo imprime "2009-06-19 22:59:59":

```js
// 19 de junho de 2009
let d = moment([2009, 5, 19]);

// 2009-06-19 22:59:59 <- caso o fuso horário esteja configurado para Dhaka, Bangladesh
console.log(d.endOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Forçando "23:59:59", você estará imprimindo um horário que não existe naquele dia, naquele timezone.

> "Ah, mas isso foi em 2009 num país distante, aqui onde eu moro isso não acontece!"

Atualmente pode até não acontecer, mas as regras de fusos-horários [mudam o tempo todo](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/). No Brasil o horário de verão mudou várias vezes ao longo do tempo: [houve uma mudança em 2018](https://g1.globo.com/economia/noticia/horario-de-verao-comecara-em-novembro-e-nao-mais-em-outubro-a-partir-de-2018-informa-planalto.ghtml), por exemplo, quando o início deixou de ser em outubro e passou a ser em novembro (e [já mudou de novo, o Brasil não terá horário de verão em 2019](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2019-2022/2019/decreto/D9772.htm), e será assim "para sempre" - ou seja, até que mude de novo). Neste momento a União Europeia [está a caminho de eliminar o horário de verão](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/eu-votes-scrap-dst.html). E a todo momento algum governo está pensando em mudar as regras do fuso horário seu país, estado, província, cidade ou o que for.

Portanto, nada garante que isso não possa acontecer no "nosso" timezone. Já que está usando uma biblioteca que cuida desses detalhes, melhor deixar a cargo das suas respectivas funções, em vez de colocar valores fixos que "funcionam" - pode até funcionar na maioria dos casos, mas já que o Moment.js também funciona para esses casos e ainda cuida das exceções mais complicadas, por que não deixá-lo cuidar disso? Usar `startOf` e `endOf` é muito mais garantido que colocar "00:00:00" e "23:59:59" diretamente no código.

---

#### Moment Timezone

Outra opção, caso deseje mostrar sempre 00:00:00, independente do timezone, é usar o [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone) e forçar um timezone específico. Para não sofrer efeitos de horário de verão, por exemplo, você pode forçar tudo para [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time):

```js
// 4 de novembro de 2018 (lembrando que janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc)
let d = moment.tz([2018, 10, 4], "UTC");

// 2018-11-04 00:00:00
console.log(d.startOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.min.js"></script>
```

Usando [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), os efeitos de horário de verão não existem mais, e agora o código imprime sempre `2018-11-04 00:00:00`, independente do timezone do sistema.

Só lembrando que meia-noite em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) não vai necessariamente ser meia-noite no fuso-horário do browser que o usuário estiver usando.

Por exemplo, meia-noite em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) corresponde a 9 da noite do dia anterior no Horário de Brasília (ou 10 da noite quando está em horário de verão). O mesmo vale para 23:59:59 (em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) poderá não ser o mesmo horário no timezone do browser).

Leve isso em consideração ao mostrar esses horários para o usuário.