# Usar a biblioteca time.h para datas

Tags: c, data

Eu queria usar a biblioteca `time.h` para armazenar uma data de nascimento tipo 26/10/2312 (neste formato) num determinado array, só que nunca trabalhei com esta biblioteca. Alguém me consegue dar uma explicação?

Comment: o que você já tentou? quais erros está enfrentando? Leia um pouco sobre [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e edite sua pergunta em seguida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [biblioteca `time.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/) contém o seguinte:

- O tipo `size_t`, que é o tipo resultante do operador `sizeof` e representa uma quantidade em bytes. Esse tipo também é definido em várias outras bibliotecas.
- O tipo `clock_t` que representa contagem de ciclos de processador.
- O tipo `time_t` que em geral representa um [timestamp unix](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/132).
- A `struct tm`, que é uma estrutura utilizada para obter a data e a hora do sistema.
- Outras funções e macros que recebem ou retornam dados com os formatos acima.

Ou seja, nenhum dos tipos disponibilizados por essa biblioteca será o que você quer, e portanto, o melhor é criar o seu próprio:

```
typedef struct date_type {
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
} date_type;
```

Com isso, você pode criar arrays assim:

```
date_type[20] minhas_datas; /* Array de 20 posições do tipo date_type. */
```

Ou então usar ponteiros do tipo `date_type *`.

Você pode fazer funções que trabalhar com `date_type` para verificar se uma data é válida, construir uma data, calcular o dia da semana, integrar com `time_t` e `struct tm`, etc. Recomendo dar uma lida no que delineei [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70604/132).

Você também pode usar a função [`strftime`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/) junto com um `sscanf` para trabalhar com o `time_t` diretamente se quiser.