# Subtrair extrair meses entre duas datas em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, data

Estou com dificuldades em calcular o total de meses entre duas datas.

Ex: datafinal (29/03/2018) - datainicial (29/01/2018) = 2 meses, entretanto as datas são fornecidas pelo Datepicker jQuery e se poderia informar o comando para alterar o valor do resultado quando alterado uma ou ambas as datas em JavaScript.

Segue o código abaixo:

```
<div class="control-form">
   <label for="">Data Inicial:</label>
   <input name="datainicial" type="text" id="calendario" value="29/01/2018"  class="form-control" >
</div>
<div class="control-form">
   <label for="">Data Final:</label>
   <input name="datafinal" type="text" id="calendario2" class="form-control" >
</div>
<div class="control-form">
   <label for="">Numero de Parcelas:</label>
   <input name="numeroparcelas" type="text" class="form-control" id="numeroparcelas">
</div>
```

Comment: A sua pergunta está muito ampla, inclua o seu código com um exemplo verificável.
Ps.: Evite cumprimentos, como a invocação dos deuses dos scripts ;)

Comment: ok, farei isso, agradeço desde já.

Comment: tem uma lib chamada moment.js uma pesquisa rápida e nunca mais terá problema com datas e javascript

Answer (score 2):

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272765/112052) já explica como pegar as datas do *date picker* sempre que uma for selecionada.

Mas eu gostaria de mencionar um detalhe no cálculo. Obter a diferença em meses não é algo tão simples quanto parece, pois há muitos fatores a serem considerados. Conforme explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/370215/112052):

> *Meses têm tamanhos variados, podendo ter 28, 29, 30 ou 31 dias, e nem sempre a conta é tão simples assim.*
>
> *Por exemplo, entre 01/01/2019 e 01/02/2019 há 31 dias. Dividindo por 30 e arredondando, dá 1 mês.*
>
> *Mas entre 01/02/2019 e 01/03/2019 há 28 dias. Dividindo por 30, dá 0,93: se arredondar pra baixo, dá zero meses. Mas entre 1 de fevereiro e 1 de março a diferença não é de um mês? Então devemos arredondar pra cima nesse caso?*
>
> *Mas e se fosse entre 01/01/2019 e 29/01/2019, a diferença também é de 28 dias. Só que entre 1 de janeiro e 29 de janeiro ainda não se passou 1 mês, então eu não posso arredondar pra cima nesse caso. "Ah, então eu só arredondo pra cima se não estiver no mesmo mês".*
>
> *Aí você vê que entre 01/01/2019 e 27/02/2019 a diferença é de 57 dias, que dividido por 30 dá 1,9. Se arredondar pra cima dá 2, mas entre 1 de janeiro e 27 de fevereiro ainda não se passaram dois meses. E agora?*

Ou seja, a forma de calcular varia de acordo com o que você quer considerar. O dia será levado em conta ou não? Entre 15 de janeiro e 10 de março tem 2 meses (pois março é "dois meses depois de janeiro"), ou só tem 1 mês (pois só depois de 15 de março é que completam 2 meses)?

Esse é o primeiro problema. Outro é o próprio `Date` do JavaScript, que esconde algumas armadilhas. Na outra resposta a string "29/01/2018" é transformada em "2018-01-29" (que é o [formato ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)). Mas quando você só tem a data (somente dia, mês e ano), e sem o horário, ele cria a data com o horário igual à meia-noite em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Esse é o primeiro problema, pois ao usar os *getters*, usa-se o timezone do ambiente (que pode não ser o mesmo que UTC). Veja este exemplo:

```js
const data = new Date("2021-01-01");
// mostrar data no timezone do browser (a saída abaixo ocorre se estiver no Horário de Brasília)
console.log(data.toString()); // Thu Dec 31 2020 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
// mostrar data em UTC
console.log(data.toISOString()); // 2021-01-01T00:00:00.000Z

// getters usam o timezone do browser
console.log(data.getDate(), data.getMonth(), data.getFullYear()); // 31 11 2020
```

No meu caso, meu browser está usando o Horário de Brasília (o Chrome pega a configuração do Sistema Operacional) - se o seu estiver usando um fuso diferente, a saída não será a mesma. Então no meu caso, criei a data referente a "2021-01-01" (1 de janeiro de 2021), mas como não informei o horário, ele seta "meia-noite em UTC". Só que meia-noite em UTC corresponde à 21h do dia anterior no Horário de Brasíla (já que este fuso está 3 horas atrás de UTC). Por isso ao usar `getMonth()` e `getDate()`, ele retorna os valores de acordo com o Horário de Brasília (lembrando que `11` equivale a dezembro, pois no `Date` do JavaScript, [janeiro é zero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405998/112052)).

Ou seja, isso pode causar alguns problemas no cálculo feito na outra resposta. Teste, por exemplo, de 01/01/2021 a 10/02/2021, e o resultado será 2 (mas entendo que deveria ser 1, pois ainda não se passaram 2 meses). Isso ocorre por causa do problema relatado acima, `getMonth()` retorna dezembro e `getFullYear()` retorna 2020.

Isso tudo acontece porque o `Date` do JavaScript na verdade representa um [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) (um ponto na linha do tempo), não uma data específica (um único valor de dia, mês, ano, hora, minuto e segundo).
Para mais detalhes, leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456089/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/455437/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/408160/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/416172/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344030/112052).

---

Uma maneira de contornar é usar o construtor que recebe os valores numéricos, pois aí ele considera meia-noite no fuso do browser (que é o mesmo fuso usado nos *getters*) e o problema acima não ocorre mais.

Mas ainda sim você tem que decidir se vai considerar o dia ou não: por exemplo, entre 15 de janeiro e 10 de março, são 2 meses (porque considero apenas "janeiro" e "março") ou 1 mês (pois somente depois de 15 de março é que completa 2 meses). Algo assim:

```js
function ajustaMesAno(data) {
    return data.getFullYear() * 12 + data.getMonth() + 1;
}

function diffMeses(inicio, fim, consideraDia = true) {
    let meses = ajustaMesAno(fim) - ajustaMesAno(inicio);
    if (consideraDia && inicio.getDate() > fim.getDate()) {
        meses--;
    }
    return meses;
}

// lembrando que janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc
const inicio = new Date(2021, 0, 15); // 15 de janeiro
const fim = new Date(2021, 2, 10); // 10 de março

// considera o dia
console.log(diffMeses(inicio, fim)); // 1

// não considera o dia
console.log(diffMeses(inicio, fim, false)); // 2
```

Ou seja, se eu considerar o dia, a diferença entre 15 de janeiro e 10 de março é de 1 mês (somente a partir de 15 março é que passaria a ser de 2 meses).

---

O exemplo completo fica assim:

```js
function construirData(str) {
    let [dia, mes, ano] = str.split("/").map(v => parseInt(v));
    return new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia);
}

function ajustaMesAno(data) {
    return data.getFullYear() * 12 + data.getMonth() + 1;
}

function diffMeses(inicio, fim, consideraDia = true) {
    let meses = ajustaMesAno(fim) - ajustaMesAno(inicio);
    if (consideraDia && inicio.getDate() > fim.getDate()) {
        meses--;
    }
    return meses;
}

function isValidDate(d) {
  return d instanceof Date && !isNaN(d);
}

function calcularDiferenca() {
    var inicio = construirData($("#calendario").val());
    if (! isValidDate(inicio)) {
        alert('Data inicial inválida');
        return;
    }
    var fim = construirData($("#calendario2").val());
    if (! isValidDate(fim)) {
        alert('Data final inválida');
        return;
    }
    if (inicio >= fim) {
        alert('Data inicial deve ser anterior à data final');
        return;
    }
    // aqui você decide se vai considerar os dias ou não
    $("#numeroparcelas").val(diffMeses(inicio, fim));
}

$('input[id*="calendario"]').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
   onSelect: calcularDiferenca
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-form">
   <label for="">Data Inicial:</label>
   <input name="datainicial" type="text" id="calendario" value="01/01/2021"  class="form-control" >
</div>
<div class="control-form">
   <label for="">Data Final:</label>
   <input name="datafinal" type="text" id="calendario2" class="form-control" >
</div>
<div class="control-form">
   <label for="">Numero de Parcelas:</label>
   <input name="numeroparcelas" type="text" class="form-control" id="numeroparcelas">
</div>
```

Incluí algumas validações na data (se de fato é uma data, e se a data inicial é menor que a final), pois se tiver algo inválido nem vale a pena calcular (a outra resposta prefere calcular sempre e só no final verificar se o resultado faz sentido, eu prefiro só fazer o cálculo se tiver certeza que todos os dados estão válidos).

No cálculo da diferença você pode escolher se considera ou não o dia, conforme exemplo anterior. Não há resposta certa, e tudo depende dos requisitos (não ficou claro se deve considerar ou não, ou se as datas sempre estarão com o mesmo dia, etc).

---

E claro que ainda tem *corner cases* que não têm resposta fácil. Por exemplo, entre 29/02/2020 e 28/02/2021, são 11 ou 12 meses? Se considerar o dia, serão 11 (pois ainda não chegou o dia 29, e o problema é que em 2021 fevereiro não tem 29 dias), e se não considerar o dia, serão 12. Mas como é o último dia do mês, não deveria ser 12 meses de diferença? Pense em alguém que nasceu em 29/02/2020: em 28/02/2021 essa pessoa já completou 1 ano? Algumas linguagens/API's dizem que sim, outras dizem que não. Cabe a você decidir o que faz sentido para o seu caso e fazer o tratamento específico, caso seja necessário.

[Aritmética de datas](https://hkotsubo.github.io/tag/aritm%C3%A9tica) é assim mesmo, [bizarra e contra-intuitiva](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/01/the-joys-of-date-time-arithmetic/).

Answer (score -1):

O *Datepicker jQuery* possui um evento `onSelect:` quando uma data é selecionada. Então você pode chamar uma função dentro desse evento e calcular:

```
$('input[id*="calendario"]').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
   onSelect: function(){
      var mesIni = $("#calendario").val().split("/");
      var mesFim = $("#calendario2").val().split("/");

      mesIni = new Date(mesIni.pop()+"-"+mesIni[1]+"-"+mesIni.shift());
      mesFim = new Date(mesFim.pop()+"-"+mesFim[1]+"-"+mesFim.shift());

      var meses = mesFim.getMonth() - mesIni.getMonth() 
      + (12 * (mesFim.getFullYear() - mesIni.getFullYear()));

      if(!isNaN(meses)) $("#numeroparcelas").val(meses);
   }
});
```

**Veja exemplo:**

```js
$('input[id*="calendario"]').datepicker({
   dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
   onSelect: function(){
      var mesIni = $("#calendario").val().split("/");
      var mesFim = $("#calendario2").val().split("/");
      
      mesIni = new Date(mesIni.pop()+"-"+mesIni[1]+"-"+mesIni.shift());
      mesFim = new Date(mesFim.pop()+"-"+mesFim[1]+"-"+mesFim.shift());
      
      var meses = mesFim.getMonth() - mesIni.getMonth() 
      + (12 * (mesFim.getFullYear() - mesIni.getFullYear()));
   
      if(!isNaN(meses)) $("#numeroparcelas").val(meses);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div class="control-form">
   <label for="">Data Inicial:</label>
   <input name="datainicial" type="text" id="calendario" value="29/01/2018"  class="form-control" >
</div>
<div class="control-form">
   <label for="">Data Final:</label>
   <input name="datafinal" type="text" id="calendario2" class="form-control" >
</div>
<div class="control-form">
   <label for="">Numero de Parcelas:</label>
   <input name="numeroparcelas" type="text" class="form-control" id="numeroparcelas">
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou aki do jeito que eu esperava, sou novato na área de programação e agradeço pela contribuição e a humildade pela ajuda. Vlw