# Como formatar data no formato ISO 8601 mantendo o fuso horário do browser?

Tags: javascript, data, datetime, formatação, timezone

```js
// data e hora atual a região
let data = new Date();
console.log(data); 
// Está retornando Fri Nov 16 2018 17:04:08 GMT-0200 (Horário brasileiro de verão)

var dataBase = data.toISOString().replace(/\.\d{3}Z$/, '');
console.log(dataBase);
// Está retornando 2018-11-16T19:04:08
```

O primeiro retorno está com fuso horário atual (correto), mas o segundo está com `+0300` e com horário de verão. Como faço para manter o mesmo formato do segundo retorno, mas com o fuso horário conforme o primeiro exemplo?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Crie uma nova data subtraindo o GMT. Usando `data.getTimezoneOffset()` você consegue pegar o GMT em minutos (ex. 0200 = 2 horas = 120 minutos).

O `data.valueOf()` irá retornar a data em `ms` (milissegundos). Então é preciso converter o GMT também em milissegundos: `data.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000`.

Agora basta subtrair o segundo do primeiro:

```
let data2 = new Date(data.valueOf() - data.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
```

Irá ficar assim:

```
// data e hora atual a região
let data = new Date();
// Fri Nov 16 2018 18:36:40 GMT-0200 (Horário de Verão de Brasília)

let data2 = new Date(data.valueOf() - data.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
var dataBase = data2.toISOString().replace(/\.\d{3}Z$/, '');
// 2018-11-16T18:36:40
```

**[Veja no JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L30nuj4f/)**

Comment: aqui no `Trecho de código` acho que fica diferente né?

Comment: Pois é. Tem coisas aqui no snippet que não funfa direito.

Comment: @Sam, o trecho que código funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado!

Answer (score 10):

Primeiro vamos entender o que representa um `Date` no JavaScript. [Segundo a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), é um objeto que representa a quantidade de milissegundos desde 1 de janeiro de 1970, à meia-noite, [em **UTC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (esta data também é chamada de **Unix Epoch**). Em outras palavras, é o valor numérico do [Unix Timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Você pode obter este valor usando os métodos [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) ou [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf). E o grande detalhe deste valor é que ele **é o mesmo em todo o mundo**.

Por exemplo, neste exato instante, se eu rodar `new Date().getTime()`, o resultado será `1542471749270`. Ou seja, este exato momento corresponde a 1542471749270 milissegundos depois do Unix Epoch. E qualquer computador, em qualquer parte do mundo, que tivesse rodado este código no mesmo instante que eu, teria obtido este mesmo resultado. O timestamp (e consequentemente o `Date` do JavaScript) representa um ponto específico na linha do tempo, um único instante.

Só que este mesmo valor pode corresponder a uma data e hora diferentes, dependendo do fuso horário em que você está:

- em São Paulo, corresponde a 17/11/2018, às 14:22:29.270 (2 da tarde do dia 17)
- em Tóquio, corresponde a **18**/11/2018, às 01:22:29.270 (1 da manhã do dia 18)
- em Los Angeles, 17/11/2018, às 08:22:29.270 (8 da manhã do dia 17)
- e em UTC, 17/11/2018, às 16:22:29.270

O valor do timestamp (e portanto, do `Date`) é o mesmo, apenas a data e hora correspondente varia conforme o timezone.

---

É por isso que a mesma data produz 2 resultados diferentes. Quando eu faço `console.log(data)`, o resultado é o mesmo do método `toString()`, que produz a string no formato `Fri Nov 16...`, e com os valores de data e hora convertidos para o timezone que o browser está usando.

*Você pode verificar o timezone do seu browser usando `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone`, só verifique se o seu browser [suporta a API Intl](https://caniuse.com/#feat=internationalization)*.

Já o método `toISOString()` retorna a data no [formato ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), mas com os [valores de data e hora ajustados para UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString). Por isso a diferença de horário que você notou.

---

#### Como resolver?

Infelizmente o JavaScript não fornece uma maneira nativa de retornar uma data no formato ISO 8601 **e ao mesmo tempo** com os valores de data e hora no timezone do browser (ou em qualquer outro que você queira, que não seja UTC).

Uma maneira de resolver isso é construir a string manualmente. Você pode usar os *getters* do objeto, que retornam os valores numéricos de data e hora de acordo com o timezone do browser.

No exemplo abaixo estou usando uma data com o timestamp 1542471749270, apenas para que a saída não mude o tempo todo. Mas no seu caso, para usar a data atual, basta mudar para `new Date()`.

```js
// data: troque por "new Date()" para a data atual
let d = new Date(1542471749270);

// formatar data no formato ISO 8601
var iso = d.getFullYear().toString() + "-";
iso += (d.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0') + "-";
iso += d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0') + "T";
iso += d.getHours().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ":";
iso += d.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0') + ":";
iso += d.getSeconds().toString().padStart(2, '0');
console.log(iso); // 2018-10-17T14:22:29
```

A saída é `2018-11-17T14:22:29` (repare que precisa somar 1 no mês, pois em JavaScript [janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405998/112052)).

Atenção para usar `getFullYear()` (que retorna 2018), em vez de `getYear()`, que [retorna o valor do ano indexado em 1900](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear#Return_value) (ou seja, neste caso, retornaria 118).

Também usei a função `padStart` para completar com zero à esquerda os valores menores que 10 (assim, `5` é mostrado como `05`). Infelizmente isso [não funciona no IE](https://caniuse.com/#feat=pad-start-end), mas você pode substituir por esta função:

```
function pad(valor) {
    if (valor < 10) {
        return "0" + valor;
    }
    return valor.toString();
}
```

---

#### E se eu usar outro timestamp?

A [resposta do Sam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/343926/112052) sugere criar outra data com o valor do timestamp modificado. De fato ela mostra o valor que você quer, mas esteja ciente de um detalhe.

Lembre-se o que é o timestamp: um valor que representa um único instante, e que é o mesmo no mundo todo. Ao criar uma data com outro valor de timestamp, você está criando um objeto que se refere a um instante diferente.

Para entender melhor, uma analogia: suponha que meu computador esteja configurado com o fuso horário errado (estou no Brasil, mas o fuso horário do sistema operacional está configurado para Londres).

Agora no Brasil são 2 da tarde, mas em Londres são 4 da tarde, então meu computador está mostrando que são 4 da tarde. O que eu posso fazer para arrumar? Há duas opções:

1. entrar nas configurações do fuso horário e mudar para o do Brasil, **ou**
2. atrasar o relógio em duas horas

Ambas vão fazer com que o relógio mostre "2 da tarde", mas a segunda opção está na verdade me mostrando um horário correspondente a 2 horas no passado: ele me mostra que é 2 da tarde, mas no fuso horário de Londres. Só que agora em Londres são 4 da tarde (no Brasil é que ainda são 2 da tarde). Quem olha só para os números do relógio acha que está tudo certo, sem saber que na verdade meu relógio está atrasado 2 horas.

É isso que acontece quando você subtrai um valor do timestamp: a data criada está no passado, só que como você está olhando ela do ponto de vista de outro timezone, ela parece estar certa (os números mostrados estão "certos").

Usando como exemplo a data acima:

```
let d = new Date(1542471749270);
```

Já vimos que ela corresponde a uma data e hora diferente em cada timezone:

- em São Paulo, corresponde a 17/11/2018, às 14:22:29.270 (2 da tarde do dia 17)
- em Tóquio, corresponde a **18**/11/2018, às 01:22:29.270 (1 da manhã do dia 18)
- em Los Angeles, 17/11/2018, às 08:22:29.270 (8 da manhã do dia 17)
- e em UTC, 17/11/2018, às 16:22:29.270

Se eu fizer o que foi proposto:

```js
let d = new Date(1542471749270);
let d2 = new Date(d.valueOf() - d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

console.log(d.toISOString());  // 2018-11-17T16:22:29.270Z
console.log(d2.toISOString()); // 2018-11-17T14:22:29.270Z
console.log(d.getTime());  // 1542471749270
console.log(d2.getTime()); // 1542464549270
```

Repare que `d2` corresponde a um instante "no passado", se comparado a `d`. Você criou uma data que corresponde a um instante completamente diferente. Graças ao método `getTimezoneOffset()`, foi possível obter o valor exato a ser subtraído para que os valores de data e hora de `d2` **em UTC** sejam iguais os valores de data e hora de `d` **no fuso horário brasileiro**. Mas de qualquer forma, `d` e `d2` correspondem a instantes diferentes.

Isso é errado? Bom, vai de cada um. Se você não vai usar `d2` para mais nada, não é tão problemático assim. Mas se for usá-lo depois, cuidado, pois ele não representa o mesmo instante que `d`. Ao fazer isso, você só "atrasou o relógio", quando o correto seria usar o timezone que você precisa (e foi o que fiz ao usar os *getters*, pois eles retornam os valores no timezone do browser, que é o que você quer).

---

#### Moment.js

Se quiser, você pode usar a biblioteca [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), que na minha opinião é "tudo que o JavaScript deveria ter nativamente para lidar com datas" (*um pouco exagerado, mas enfim*).

Com ela fica um pouco mais fácil obter o formato desejado:

```js
// use "moment()" para a data/hora atual
let d = moment(1542471749270);

// por padrão, já usa o timezone do browser (em vez de UTC)
console.log(d.format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss')); // 2018-11-17T14:22:29
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

O método `format` usará os valores de data e hora correspondentes ao timezone do browser, que é o que você precisa, sem a necessidade de fazer "malabarismos" com o valor do timestamp.

Pode parecer exagero adicionar uma biblioteca só para isso, mas se vai fazer mais operações com datas, é altamente recomendado (dê uma olhada na [documentação](https://momentjs.com/docs) e tente fazer todas aquelas operações com JavaScript nativo ).

Se precisar converter entre timezones, pode usar em conjunto com o [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

---

Veja mais sobre datas e timezones no JavaScript [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/455444/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/456089/112052).

Answer (score -6):

new Date().toLocaleString();
//'11/11/2021 16:52:30'

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).