# Não consigo obter hora do timeStamp correta

Tags: javascript, node.js, data, timestamp, momentjs

Tenho uma API que estou consumindo
e nela tenho campo **timeStamp** com valor **1604327859** e
com esse valor tenho a seguinte hora e data:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse valor acima é o correto, estou usando o pacote Moment.js, mas o valor que está me retornando é **1970-01-19T10:38:47-03:00** e está errado.

A  execução do código está da seguinte maneira:

```
var moment = require('moment'); // require
console.log(moment(1604327859).format())
```

Answer (score 1):

O valor do [*timestamp*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) pode estar em diferentes unidades de tempo. O mais comum é estar em segundos ou milissegundos, e cada API/linguagem costuma trabalhar com um deles.

No caso do Moment.js, ele trabalha com o valor em milissegundos, mas o valor que você tem está em segundos.

Sendo assim, ou você multiplica este valor por 1000, ou usa [`moment.unix`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/unix-timestamp/), que recebe o valor em segundos.

Outro detalhe é que [`format`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/), por padrão, retorna a data e hora referente ao fuso horário do ambiente no qual o código roda (seja o do *browser* ou das configurações do Node, por exemplo - veja [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/456649/112052), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344030/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/455444/112052) para mais detalhes).

Como você quer a data/hora em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), pode usar [`utc()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) no `moment` criado, assim `format()` retornará a data/hora em UTC:

```js
console.log(moment.unix(1604327859).utc().format());
console.log(moment(1604327859 * 1000).utc().format());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Ambos vão imprimir "2020-11-02T14:37:39Z".

---

Só lembrando que, tecnicamente, "2020-11-02T11:37:39-03:00" não está errado, afinal um *timestamp* representa um instante único, um ponto na linha do tempo, mas pode corresponder a diferentes datas/horas dependendo do timezone (fuso horário). Basta considerar por exemplo o "agora". Neste exato momento, em cada parte do mundo - em cada fuso horário - a data e hora atual podem ser diferentes, mas o instante (o valor do *timestamp*) é o mesmo para todos.

Sendo assim, o *timestamp* 1604327859 representa um único instante absoluto, e ele corresponde tanto a "2020-11-02T11:37:39-03:00" (11 da manhã no Horário de Brasília) quanto a "2020-11-02T14:37:39Z" (14h em UTC). O `-03:00` é o [*offset*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) (a diferença com relação a UTC, e no caso, indica que a data/hora em questão está 3 horas atrás de UTC, e portanto **ambos** correspondem ao mesmo instante - ao mesmo *timestamp*).

---

Outra opção é usar o [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs):

```js
console.log(moment.tz(1604327859 * 1000, "UTC").format()); // 2020-11-02T14:37:39Z
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Repare que o *timestamp* deve estar em milissegundos, e é possível informar o timezone (podendo, no caso, ser "UTC"), assim `format()` não usará o fuso do ambiente.

Esta forma é preferível se você precisar converter para outros timezones além de UTC. Ex:

```js
let ts = 1604327859 * 1000;
// timezone do Japão
console.log(moment.tz(ts, "Asia/Tokyo").format()); // 2020-11-02T23:37:39+09:00
// timezone da Alemanha
console.log(moment.tz(ts, "Europe/Berlin").format()); // 2020-11-02T15:37:39+01:00
// Horário de Brasília
console.log(moment.tz(ts, "America/Sao_Paulo").format()); // 2020-11-02T11:37:39-03:00
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esse retorno acontece devido ao formato de data que você está enviando, unixtimestamp (mais informações: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/).
Tente ajustar seu código para:

```
var moment = require('moment'); // require
console.log(moment.unix(1604327859).format())
```

Assim você especifica para o moment que o formato de entrada da data é unixtimestamp.

Comment: A reposta ainda não saiu totalmente completa, a hora saiu errada, só a data está correta 2020-11-02T11:37:39-03:00

Comment: Ferreira, isso devido ao GMT.

Comment: Existe algo que possa contornar essa falha usando o pacote?