# Bug no Javascript que subtrai dia em -1 e adiciona horário em meses+dias com 2 dígitos

Tags: javascript, data

Estava fazendo uma interação com um componente de calendário feito com JavaScript puro, passando um array de datas para o componente para o mesmo selecionar as datas correspondentes no calendário.

Notei que quando eu mandava ranges de datas de um mês completo, as datas eram adicionadas efetivamente, menos em **Outubro**, **Novembro** e **Dezembro**.

A princípio pensei que era bug do plugin, posteriormente verifiquei que o problema estava na verdade no parse do objeto `Date` utilizando **hífen** e somente em **meses+dias** com **2** dígitos...

**O bug subtrai uma 1 dia na data final, e seta um horário na data.**

**O valor fica correto com meses com 1 dígito:**
[image: cro]

**O valor fica incorreto com meses com 2 dígitos:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O valor fica correto se não usar hífen:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe o motivo disso?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De acordo com a [especificação](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), o formato em questão ("ano-mês-dia", formato definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)) deve ter o mês e dia sempre com 2 dígitos.

Qualquer coisa diferente disso terá um comportamento indefinido, e dependente do browser/ambiente no qual o código roda. Por exemplo, testando no Firefox (versão 68.0.2 Windows 64 bits), tanto `new Date('2019-9-10')` quanto `new Date('2019-09-10')` deram o mesmo resultado. Mas no Chrome (versão 76.0.3809.132 Windows 64 bits) e no Node (versão 14), os resultados foram diferentes, da forma que você relatou.

No meu entendimento, este comportamento está de acordo com [este trecho da especificação](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date.parse):

> *If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.*

Em tradução livre:

> Se a string não estiver de acordo com este formato, pode ser usada qualquer heurística ou formato específico da implementação.

Ou seja, como `2019-9-10` não se encaixa no formato especificado, cada browser trata da forma que achar melhor.

---

Dito isso, [na documentação de `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Timestamp_string) há o seguinte aviso:

> *date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC*

Em tradução livre:

> strings contendo somente a data (por exemplo, "1970-01-01") são tratadas como [**UTC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Além disso, a [documentação também diz](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Individual_date_and_time_component_values) que os campos de horário, quando omitidos, são setados para zero.

Isso quer dizer que `new Date('2019-09-10')` (repare que o mês está escrito com dois dígitos) cria uma data correspondente a 10 de setembro de 2019 à meia-noite (00:00:00.000) em [**UTC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

Mas quando você imprime uma data (seja com `console.log`, ou quando o próprio console do browser mostra o valor criado), ela é convertida para o fuso-horário do browser (que por sua vez, *geralmente* usa o que está configurado no sistema operacional).

No seu caso, pelos resultados, o fuso horário é o Horário Oficial de Brasília.

E como **10 de setembro de 2019 à meia-noite em UTC** é igual à **9 de setembro de 2019, às 21h no Horário de Brasília**, você vê essa "diferença". De maneira geral, os fusos horários do Brasil sempre estão algumas horas atrás do UTC (o Horário de Brasília está 3 horas atrás - ou duas, quando é horário de verão), então qualquer data criada à meia-noite em UTC corresponderá ao dia anterior no Horário de Brasília.

---

Quando o mês está com apenas um dígito, o Chrome considera que é meia-noite no fuso horário do browser (no caso, meia-noite no Horário de Brasília), e não em UTC (como acontece quando o mês possui 2 dígitos). Como eu já disse, *provavelmente* é algum detalhe de implementação, que é diferente do Firefox (pois nesse browser, em ambos os casos, o resultado foi meia-noite em UTC).

Outro ponto que pode explicar essa diferença é que a padronização do formato só foi definida no [ES5](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262%205th%20edition%20December%202009.pdf#sec-0.15.9.1.15) (em 2009). Antes disso, cada browser implementava diferentes formatos (e com diferentes resultados), que podiam ou não funcionar em outros browsers, podendo ter ou não o mesmo comportamento. Muitos foram mantidos até hoje por motivos de retrocompatibilidade (como provavelmente é o caso de `2019/09/10`), e por isso, não há garantia que vão funcionar da mesma maneira em todos os browsers.

De qualquer forma, se quer manter o mesmo comportamento independente do mês, você tem duas opções:

1. se quer o horário à meia-noite em **UTC** (que pode não corresponder ao mesmo dia no fuso horário do browser), use sempre o mês com 2 dígitos na string (`2019-09-10` em vez de `2019-9-10`).
2. se quer o horário à meia-noite **no fuso horário do browser**, pode usar o construtor que recebe os valores numéricos. Por exemplo, `new Date(2019, 8, 10)` cria uma data referente à 10 de setembro de 2019, à meia-noite, no timezone do browser (sim, você [tem que subtrair 1 do mês](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/405994/112052), pois os meses são indexados em zero: janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc).

- outra maneira de forçar a hora para meia-noite no fuso horário do browser é usar o mês e dia com 2 dígitos e incluir o horário: `new Date('2019-09-10T00:00')`

Comment: Entao, o problema é que não tive bug algum com datas com mês com 1 digitos (janeiro a setembro), só tive problema com os meses que tem 2, novembro a dezembro.
Apesar que essa parte do fuso-horario poderia ter alguma relaçao, esse erro acontece somente em meses com 2 digitos, e datas com 2 digitos, 2019-12-9 não da erro, mas com 2019-12-10 acontece.

Comment: @EJSpawn É o que eu disse, se usar mês ou dia com 1 dígito, o formato não é mais o aceito na especificação e cada browser vai tratar de um jeito (no Chrome dá diferença, no Firefox não). Eu não considero *bug* porque a especificação diz que isso pode acontecer (qualquer formato que não tenha o mês e dia com 2 dígitos será dependente da implementação). De qualquer forma, eu sugiro sempre colocar com 2 dígitos, e se quiser pode forçar o horário para meia-noite, pois aí ele passa a considerar o horário local. Ex: `new Date('2019-12-09T00:00')` (adicione "T00:00" para forçar a hora pra meia-noite)

Comment: No meu caso eu não pude setar a hora para meia noite, mas validei que efetivamente ele resolveria o problema. Outra solução que serviu melhor pro meu caso era, criar uma function que retornasse a data sem fuso horário:
data.valueOf() - data.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000

Comment: @EJSpawn Na verdade, ao subtrair do `valueOf` vc está criando uma data no passado (que por coincidência pode mostrar um valor de data e hora "correto"). Eu explico isso em detalhes [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344030/112052) (está na seção "E se eu usar outro timestamp?", mas é interessante ler tudo para entender melhor o que de fato acontece ao subtrair do `valueOf`) :-) Inclusive, no início da resposta eu explico porque um `Date` do JavaScript na verdade não tem fuso horário...

Answer (score -2):

eu montei uma função que resolveu esse meu problema em converter data ISO em UTC, dando a sensação de '1 dia a menos' no resultado.

Uma função bem simples:

```
function formatDateISOToUTC(dateISO){
if (dateISO == null || dateISO == undefined || dateISO == ""){
    return null;
}
var dataArray = dateISO.split('-');
dataArray[2] + "/" + dataArray[1] + "/" + dataArray[0];

return new Date(dataArray);
```

}

No meu caso, apliquei em um processo que compara 2 datas UTC para checar a SLA e vigência de um atendimento.