# Converter string de data sem pontuação em formato Date Javascript

Tags: javascript, data

Estou querendo formatar uma string de data sem pontuação em um campo com formato de data, por exemplo:

```js
sdata = '201909091504'

datacorreta = '2019-09-09 15:04' // resultado esperado
```

Tentei com o `.parse` mas ele me retornou um valor nulo. O que poderia usar para converter neste formato com pontuação?

Comment: O formato vai ser sempre o mesmo, ano-mes-dia hora:minutos?

Comment: `sdata.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/)` depois é só concatenar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você vai ter de formatar manualmente pois o javascript não aceita formatação personalizada de inputs/entradas de datas. Contando que você trabalhe sempre no mesmo formato, pode usar a função abaixo:

```js
sdata = '201909091504'
//datacorreta = '2019-09-09 15:05' //

function dataAPartirDeNumero(dataNumero) {
  dataFormatada = dataNumero.slice(0,4) +
    '-' + dataNumero.slice(4,6) +
    '-' + dataNumero.slice(6,8) +
    ' ' + dataNumero.slice(8,10) +
    ':' + dataNumero.slice(10,12);
   return dataFormatada;
}

dataFormatada = dataAPartirDeNumero(sdata);
console.log('data: '+ dataFormatada); //2019-09-09 15:04
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente Leonardo, era isso que eu precisava! Pensei que existia um método pronto para isso hehe

Answer (score 2):

Nativamente, o [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) do JavaScript não dá muitas opções para converter strings para uma data (na verdade, [poucos formatos são de fato "oficiais"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/408168/112052) e muitos outros funcionam de maneira diferente dependendo do *browser*).

O jeito é manipular a string manualmente. Uma forma de fazer é:

```js
let sdata = '201909091504';
let [ano, mes, dia, hora, minuto] = sdata.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/).slice(1, 6);
let dataFormatada = `${ano}-${mes}-${dia} ${hora}:${minuto}`;
console.log(dataFormatada); // 2019-09-09 15:04
```

A expressão regular usada no método `match` usa o [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d` (que corresponde a dígitos de 0 a 9) e usa os [quantificadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) `{n}` para pegar exatamente `n` dígitos. Eu também uso [parênteses](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), que formam grupos de captura, assim cada trecho em questão é retornado separadamente.

Em seguida eu uso [o método `slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) para pegar o trecho do array que me interessa (já que [`match` retorna um array com várias outras informações](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value)), atribuo às respectivas variáveis (usando a [sintaxe de *destructuring assingment*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)) e concateno tudo.

---

Um detalhe é que o código acima não verifica se a data é válida (se o dia é maior que 31, etc). Se quiser fazer isso, uma forma é:

```js
function pad(valor) {
    return valor.toString().padStart(2, '0');
}

let sdata = '201909091504';
let [ano, mes, dia, hora, minuto] = sdata.match(/(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})/).slice(1, 6).map(s => parseInt(s));
let d = new Date(ano, mes - 1, dia, hora, minuto);
if (d.getFullYear() === ano && d.getMonth() + 1 === mes && d.getDate() === dia
    && d.getHours() === hora && d.getMinutes() === minuto) {
    let dataFormatada = `${ano}-${pad(mes)}-${pad(dia)} ${pad(hora)}:${pad(minuto)}`;
    console.log(dataFormatada); // 2019-09-09 15:04
} else {
    console.log('data inválida');
}
```

Eu crio um `Date` usando os valores obtidos pela regex (convertendo-os para números com `parseInt`). Em seguida, eu verifico se os valores do `Date` são os mesmos das variáveis originais. Fiz isso porque o construtor de `Date` aceita valores como dia 32 e faz alguns ajustes (32 de janeiro é ajustado para primeiro de fevereiro, por exemplo). Então se algum dos valores for diferente, é porque a data original contém valores inválidos.

Também repare que subtraí 1 do mês porque no `Date` do JavaScript [os meses são indexados em zero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405998/112052) (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc).

---

Outra alternativa é usar o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/):

```js
let sdata = '201909091504';
let data = moment(sdata, 'YYYYMMDDHHmm'); // lê o formato acima e cria a data
// mostra a data em outro formato
console.log(data.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')); // 2019-09-09 15:04
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Uma vantagem do Moment.js é que ele também valida a data. Basta usar [`isValid()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/), conforme mostrado na [resposta do Virgilio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/413329/112052).

Comment: Uau, o regex é até simples, mas você mitou em utilizá-lo em combinação com o slice em apenas uma única linha. Claps.

Comment: Faz muita falta os métodos `fromFormat` e `format` no `Date`...

Comment: @LeonardoGetulio Eu até tentei ver se tinha como `match` retornar só o que preciso, mas no fim achei mais fácil usar o `slice` mesmo :-)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Faz muita falta uma API nativa de datas que seja decente :-)

Comment: procurando mais um pouco achei a lib date-fns, que poderia ser uma solução ao moment, já que pra usar ele temos que baixar a lib inteira no projeto e isso é meio zoado, porém não achei nenhum exemplo utilizando neste formato que descrevi no post. Se alguém souber utilizar essa lib poderia nos ajudar.

Comment: @SergioRBJ Nunca usei o date-fns, mas pelo que vi, bastaria usar os [formatos indicados na documentação](https://date-fns.org/v2.4.1/docs/parse) (veja as letras correspondentes ao ano, mês, dia, etc e monte o formato desejado). Para transformar a string em uma data, use o `parse`, e para converter para o novo formato, use `format`

Answer (score 1):

Bom, também existe um cara que pode formatar isso para você e também verificar se isso realmente é uma data válida com a biblioteca [moment.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js), exemplo:

```js
sdata = '201909091504'
var result = moment(sdata, 'YYYYMMDDHHmm');
if (result.isValid())
{
   var htmlDiv = document.getElementById("new");
   htmlDiv.innerHTML = result.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');   
}
else 
{
   alert('date invalid');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

<div>
  201909091504
</div>  
<div id="new">
  
</div>
```

Comment: +1 por lembrar do `isValid` (que eu acabei esquecendo de mencionar na minha resposta) :-)