# Problemas com retorno de data correta com "new Date()"

Tags: javascript, data

```js
let dataSTR = '1988-03-01'
let data = new Date(dataSTR)
let dataTimestamp = new Date(dataSTR).getTime()
console.log('[dataSTR]', dataSTR);
console.log('[Timestamp]', dataTimestamp);
console.log('[new Date]', data);
console.log('[formato Desejado]', `${data.getFullYear()}-${(data.getMonth())}-${data.getDate()}`);
```

O problema é basicamente o "[formato Desejado]"

Mesmo eu adicionando "+1" ao `getMonth()` ele retorna  a data com um dia a menos

```js
let dataSTR = '1988-03-01'
let data = new Date(dataSTR)
let dataTimestamp = new Date(dataSTR).getTime()
console.log('[dataSTR]', dataSTR);
console.log('[Timestamp]', dataTimestamp);
console.log('[new Date]', data);
console.log('[formato Desejado]', `${data.getFullYear()}-${(data.getMonth()+1)}-${data.getDate()}`);
```

Comment: alguem sabe explicar o porque de quando eu troco a string `dataSTR = '1988-03-01'` por `dataSTR = '1988-03-1'` o "[formato Desejado]" funciona corretamente?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters), quando uma string é passada para o construtor de `Date`, ele aceita os mesmos formatos aceitos por [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse). Este método, por sua vez, segue algumas regras.

Quando a string possui **somente** a data (ano, mês e dia), no formato "YYYY-MM-DD" (que é o formato definido pela [norma ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)), a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format) diz que este é interpretado como [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (além disso, [considera-se que o horário é meia-noite](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Individual_date_and_time_component_values)).

O problema é que os métodos *getters* (como `getMonth()`, `getDate()`, etc), retornam os valores de acordo com o timezone do browser (que *geralmente* segue o fuso horário configurado no sistema operacional).

No meu caso, por exemplo, meu browser está configurado com o Horário de Brasília. Ao criar `new Date('1988-03-01')`, estou na verdade dizendo que a data é "1 de março de 1988 à meia-noite em UTC". E 1 de março de 1988 à meia-noite em UTC corresponde a 29 de fevereiro às 21:00 no Horário de Brasília.

Ao usar os *getters*, os valores retornados correspondem ao timezone do *browser* (que nem sempre será igual a UTC), por isso dá essa "diferença de 1 dia". Ex:

```js
let data = new Date('1988-03-01');
// meu browser está no Horário de Brasília, o resultado pode variar de acordo com a config do seu
console.log(`${data.getFullYear()}-${(data.getMonth()+1)}-${data.getDate()}`); // 1988-2-29
```

---

Felizmente, existem métodos para obter os valores de acordo com UTC (como `getUTCMonth`, `getUTCDate`, etc):

```js
let data = new Date('1988-03-01');
console.log(`${data.getUTCFullYear()}-${(data.getUTCMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, '0')}-${data.getUTCDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')}`); // 1988-03-01
```

Também usei [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) para colocar o zero à esquerda do mês e dia (assim é escrito `03` em vez de `3`).

---

Quanto ao [seu comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/430642/problemas-com-retorno-de-data-correta-com-new-date-javascript-iniciante/430653#comment834276_430642), que "funciona" quando a string é `1988-03-1`, na verdade isso depende do browser.

Segundo [este trecho da especificação ECMAScript](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-date.parse): "se a string não estiver de acordo com este formato, pode ser usada qualquer heurística ou formato específico da implementação."

No caso, "este formato" refere-se ao ISO 8601, que define que o dia e mês sempre são escritos com 2 dígitos. Então quando a string é `1988-03-1` (o dia com 1 dígito apenas), o formato não é mais o ISO 8601, e portanto cada browser pode interpretar de um jeito diferente. O Chrome acaba considerando que a data está no timezone do browser, e os *getters* acabam retornando o resultado correto. Mas no Firefox, ele continua considerando UTC, e o erro ocorre do mesmo jeito (veja uma discussão mais detalhada sobre essas diferenças [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/408168/112052)).

Comment: Resolveu o meu problema, obrigado !