# Converter String to Date e verificar se é uma data válida em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, data

Estou tentando transformar um número em data, por exemplo:

Passo a string: `'00260030062016'`

Preciso pegar os últimos números `30062016` e transformar na data `30/06/2016`.
Após isso, preciso verificar se essa data é válida.

Tentei usar:

```
verificarData(numero) {
      const dataNumero = new Date(numero.substring(6, 14));
      console.log(dataCertificado);
  }
```

Porém me retorna **Invalid date.**
Será que vou ter que usar splits para isso e concatenar com "/" para depois transformar em uma data?

Usei `Date.parse()` mas me retornou `NaN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O [construtor de `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) não aceita qualquer string em qualquer formato. No caso, a string `30062016` de fato não é aceita. E chamar [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) com a mesma string não adianta, pois tanto `parse` quanto o construtor aceitam os mesmos formatos.

[Veja na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format) os formatos que são aceitos. Qualquer formato diferente do que está ali *pode* ou não funcionar, dependendo da implementação de cada browser ([veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/408168/112052) um exemplo em que um formato específico dá diferença entre browsers).

De qualquer forma, uma maneira de verificar se a data é válida é extrair os trechos que você precisa e convertê-los para números, passando-os para o construtor de `Date`:

```js
function dataValida(s) {
    let dia = parseInt(s.substring(6, 8));
    let mes = parseInt(s.substring(8, 10)) - 1;
    let ano = parseInt(s.substring(10));
    if (isNaN(dia) || isNaN(mes) || isNaN(ano)) return false;

    let d = new Date(ano, mes, dia);
    return dia == d.getDate() && mes == d.getMonth() && ano == d.getFullYear();
}

[ '00260030062016', '00260032012019', '00260030xy2016'].forEach(s => {
  console.log(`${s} válido? ${dataValida(s) ? 'sim' : 'não' }`);
});
```

Eu uso [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) para converter cada trecho para número. Se algum deles não for número, a função já retorna `false`, pois não se trata de uma data.

Eu tive que subtrair 1 do mês porque em JavaScript os meses são indexados em zero (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc - [veja aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405998/112052) para mais detalhes).

Depois eu crio a data e verifico se os valores do dia, mês e ano são os mesmos que eu obtive da string. Isso pode parecer estranho, mas se você criar uma data no dia 32 de janeiro, por exemplo, o construtor de `Date` ajusta para 1 de fevereiro. Então se os valores retornados pelos *getters* forem diferentes, você sabe que algum valor inválido foi passado.