# Criação de data a partir de um string

Tags: javascript, data

Estou tentando criar um `Date object` a partir de uma string do tipo `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Testando em um console javascript, por exemplo:

```
new Date("2021-06-20")
```

A saída é:

```
Sat Jun 19 2021 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)
```

Por que a data retornada é sempre a do dia anterior?

Comment: Fazendo `new Date("2021-6-20")`, sem o zero antes do mês, a saída é a esperada: `Sun Jun 20 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Brasilia Standard Time)`...

Comment: Conforme já dito na [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/408168/112052) no link já indicado acima, ao colocar o mês sem o zero, o resultado varia de um browser pra outro (então eu não diria que é uma boa solução). De qualquer forma, lá está explicado porque o problema ocorre, e no final da resposta tem algumas opções para contorná-lo.