# Como atribuir valores em um JSON em relação ao objeto anterior?

Tags: javascript

eu recebo um JSON e preciso alterar o valores que recebo dele.

```
[
    {
        "dataMarcacao": "10/09/2021",
        "dataenvioPS": "2021-09-10",
        "marcacao": "06:00",
        "tipo": "E",
        "registro": "I",
        "dthr_marcacao": "10/09/2021 06:00",
        "cod_acerto": "A"
    },
    {
        "dataMarcacao": "10/09/2021",
        "dataenvioPS": "2021-09-10",
        "marcacao": "09:00",
        "tipo": "E",
        "registro": "I",
        "dthr_marcacao": "10/09/2021 09:00",
        "cod_acerto": "A"
    },
    {
        "dataMarcacao": "10/09/2021",
        "dataenvioPS": "2021-09-10",
        "marcacao": "12:00",
        "tipo": "S",
        "registro": "I",
        "dthr_marcacao": "10/09/2021 12:00",
        "cod_acerto": "A"
    },
    {
        "dataMarcacao": "10/09/2021",
        "dataenvioPS": "2021-09-10",
        "marcacao": "12:50",
        "tipo": "E",
        "registro": "I",
        "dthr_marcacao": "10/09/2021 12:50",
        "cod_acerto": "A"
    }
]
```

Criei um metódo de Ordenação em relação a data, mas preciso alterar o valores do tipo. O primeiro tipo sempre tem q ser "E" (entrada) , e a partir daí uma sequencia 2° tipo "S" (saída) , 3° "E" e assim sucessivamente, e posso ter somente 4 batidas ou posso ter n batidas. Como posso resolver isso ?

```js
corrigirMarcacoes(file){

    let ordenar = file;

    ordenar.sort( function(a,b) {
      return new Date(a.dthr_marcacao).getTime() - new Date(b.dthr_marcacao).getTime();  
    });

    let tempPickList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(ordenar));
  
    if (tempPickList[0].tipo === 'E') {
      tempPickList[1].tipo = 'S';
      tempPickList[2].tipo = 'E';
      tempPickList[3].tipo = 'S';
      tempPickList[4].tipo = 'E';
      tempPickList[5].tipo = 'S';
      tempPickList[6].tipo = 'E';
      
    }
    
    console.log ('tempPickList = ', tempPickList);
    console.log('ordenar = ' , JSON.stringify(ordenar))
    return tempPickList; 
  }
```

Eu tenho esse codigo, mas ele não funciona por eu não saber o tamanho do meu JSON, por isso nao posso setar o tamanho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Veja na [resposta do hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/535121/137387) a explicação, muito boa, sobre os possíveis formatos de datas e a influência desses formatos na ordenação das datas.

Use um [Generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator):

```js
const data = [{ "dataMarcacao": "10/09/2021",  "dataenvioPS": "2021-09-10", "marcacao": "06:00",  "tipo": "E", "registro": "I",  "dthr_marcacao": "10/09/2021 06:00", "cod_acerto": "A"}, {"dataMarcacao": "10/09/2021", "dataenvioPS": "2021-09-10", "marcacao": "09:00",  "tipo": "E",      "registro": "I",  "dthr_marcacao": "10/09/2021 09:00", "cod_acerto": "A"}, {      "dataMarcacao": "10/09/2021",  "dataenvioPS": "2021-09-10","marcacao": "12:00",  "tipo": "S", "registro": "I",  "dthr_marcacao": "10/09/2021 12:00", "cod_acerto": "A" }, {"dataMarcacao": "10/09/2021",  "dataenvioPS": "2021-09-10", "marcacao": "12:50",  "tipo": "E", "registro": "I",  "dthr_marcacao": "10/09/2021 12:50", "cod_acerto": "A"}];

//Função geradora cíclica que retorna indefinida E,S,E,S,.....
function* genEI() {
  while (true) {
    yield "E";    //Retorna E e abandona a função.
    yield "S";    //Retorna S e abandona a função.
  }
}

//Obtém o Generator partir da função geradora. 
const getEI = genEI();

//Ordenação por data apresentada na pergunta.
let newData = data.sort((a, b) => {
  return new Date(a.dthr_marcacao).getTime() -
    new Date(b.dthr_marcacao).getTime();
});

//Para cada objeto e no array newData...
for (let e of newData) {
  e.tipo = getEI.next().value;       //...substitui o valor da propriedade e.tipo por um valor obtido do gerador getEI.
}

console.log(newData);
```

Um Generator é um objeto retornado por uma [função geradora](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*), esse objeto está em conformidade com o [protocolo iterável](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#iterable) e o [protocolo de iteração](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#iterator).

Geradores são funções cuja execução pode ser interrompida e posteriormente reconduzida. Seus contextos ficarão salvos entre cada recondução. Veja a explicação feita na documentação:

> Chamar uma função geradora não executa seu conteúdo imediatamente; ao
> invés disso um objeto iterator é retornado. Quando o método next() do
> objeto iterator é chamado, o conteúdo da função do gerador é executado
> até a primeira expressão yield, que especifica o valor a ser devolvido
> do iterator ou com yield* que delega para outra função geradora. O
> método next() retorna um objeto com uma propriedade value contendo o
> valor retornado e a propriedade boolean: done indicando se o gerador
> produziu seu último valor. Chamar o método next() com um argumento
> resumirá a execução da função geradora, substituindo a expressão yield
> onde a execução foi pausada com o argumento de next().
>
> Uma expressão return em um gerador, quando executada, fará com que o
> gerador termine (isto é, a propriedade done do objeto retornado será
> atribuído com o valor true). Se um valor foi retornado, este será
> usado como propriedade value do objeto retornado pelo gerador.
> Semelhantemente a uma expressão return, um erro lançado dentro do
> gerador o terminará -- a não ser que tratado no corpo do gerador.
> Quando um gerador estiver terminado, chamadas next subsequentes não
> executarão nenhum código do gerador, retornarão simplesmente um objeto
> da seguinte forma: {value: undefined, done: true}.

Comment: Funcionou pra mim, obrigado !! Consegui tbm outra forma puxando pelo índice tempPickList.forEach( function (value, index) {
      
      if (index % 2 === 0) {
        value.tipo = 'E';
      
      } else {
        value.tipo = 'S';
      }
    });

Comment: @Rabelo Inclusive eu acho mais simples assim usando o próprio índice. Mas tem um detalhe na ordenação das datas que menciono na [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/535121/112052), vale a pena dar uma olhada

Comment: @hkotsubo, citei sua resposta na minha pois eu gosto de como você escreve e explica as coisas e eu não conseguiria fazer tão bem quanto você fez.

Answer (score 2):

> *por eu não saber o tamanho do meu JSON*

É claro que você sabe. Repare que ele é delimitado por `[ ]`, o que significa que é um array. E todo array tem a propriedade `length` que indica o seu tamanho.

Na verdade, pelo seu código, você provavelmente tem um array do JavaScript, e não um JSON (apesar de "parecidos", eles [não são a mesma coisa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/517767/112052)).

Porque se fosse um JSON mesmo (ou seja, uma string contendo os dados neste formato), você não conseguiria chamar `sort` nele.

---

Mas enfim, vamos por partes.

Primeiro, você está criando as datas passando os valores "dd/mm/aaaa" direto para o construtor de `Date`. Só que nem sempre isso funciona, pois alguns browsers interpretam isso como "mm/dd/aaaa" (ou seja, `new Date("10/09/2021 10:00")` pode ser interpretado como 9 de outubro, e não 10 de setembro). Conforme já explicado [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/408168/112052), o único formato que funciona em todos os ambientes é o [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) ('aaaa-mm-ddThh:mm'). Enfim, tem que ajustar isso se quiser ordenar corretamente pela data.

Depois, `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(algo))` me parece completamente desnecessário. Se a ideia era criar uma cópia do array, use apenas `slice`. Mas se a ideia é usar o mesmo array, não faça nada (lembre-se que `sort` altera o array, então tem que ver se você quer ou não alterar o array original).

Depois, basta iterar pelo array, e nas posições pares você coloca o "E", e nas ímpares coloca o "S":

```js
    
// converte dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm para aaaa-mm-ddThh:mm
function getTimestamp(str) {
    const [data, hora] = str.split(' ');
    const [dia, mes, ano] = data.split('/');
    return new Date(`${ano}-${mes}-${dia}T${hora}`).getTime();
}

let dados = [
    { "dataMarcacao": "10/09/2021", "dataenvioPS": "2021-09-10", "marcacao": "12:50", "registro": "I", "dthr_marcacao": "10/09/2021 12:50", "cod_acerto": "A" },
    { "dataMarcacao": "10/09/2021", "dataenvioPS": "2021-09-10", "marcacao": "09:00", "registro": "I", "dthr_marcacao": "10/09/2021 09:00", "cod_acerto": "A" },
    { "dataMarcacao": "10/09/2021", "dataenvioPS": "2021-09-10", "marcacao": "06:00", "registro": "I", "dthr_marcacao": "10/09/2021 06:00", "cod_acerto": "A" },
    { "dataMarcacao": "10/09/2021", "dataenvioPS": "2021-09-10", "marcacao": "12:00", "registro": "I", "dthr_marcacao": "10/09/2021 12:00", "cod_acerto": "A" }
];

// se quiser copiar o array, use slice (senão use o próprio "dados" mesmo)
let copia = dados.slice();

copia.sort((a, b) => getTimestamp(a.dthr_marcacao) - getTimestamp(b.dthr_marcacao));
for (let i = 0; i < copia.length; i++) {
    copia[i].tipo = i % 2 == 0 ? 'E' : 'S';
}

console.log(copia);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @hkotsubo - eu tenho que usar o JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(algo) , pq recebo um erro "Cannot assign to read only property 'tipo' of object '#<Object>'" caso não use esse método, sobre o .sort alterar o array é por isso que uso uma cópia e nao o array original.