# Como obter a data do sistema em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, data

É uma pergunta simples imagino, estou começando meu estudos em JavaScript e gostaria de saber como pegar a data do computador (ano, mês, dia, hora, minuto e segundo).

Além disso, a data já vem com fuso-horário? Se não, como posso converter?

Comment: A clase Date não lhe atende? https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Como tinha dito estou começando rs rs, acabei de ver, me atende sim, obrigado!

Comment: Opa, show, bons estudos! :)

Comment: Sobre "já vem com fuso horário", talvez isso ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/455444/112052

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), mas como você mencionou uma preocupação com o fuso horário, há alguns detalhes a se atentar.

Ao contrário do que afirmou a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/456103/112052), um `Date` **não vem** no fuso horário que o dispositivo está configurado. Na verdade, o `Date` não tem informação nenhuma sobre o fuso horário (veja mais detalhes na [especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-objects)).

[Conforme explicado aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/455444/112052), o `Date` na verdade representa um [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052): a quantidade de milissegundos decorrida desde o [*Unix Epoch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (que por sua vez equivale a `1970-01-01T00:00Z` - 1 de janeiro de 1970 à meia-noite, em [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC)).

Ou seja, o `Date` representa um instante único, um ponto na linha do tempo. Pense no "agora": neste exato momento, que dia é hoje e que horas são? Em cada parte do mundo, a resposta será diferente (em algumas partes do mundo, é 10 de junho, em outras pode ser dia 9 ou 11, e o horário também será diferente). Apesar da data e hora serem diferentes, o instante (o valor do timestamp) é o mesmo para todos. E o `Date` só guarda a informação do timestamp.

Quando você imprime a data (via `alert` ou `console.log`) ou quando obtém informações dela (seja via os *getters* ou `toString()`), este timestamp é convertido para o fuso horário que está configurado no ambiente onde o código está rodando. Ou seja, o `Date` **usa** a configuração do fuso horário para converter o timestamp para os valores corretos de data e hora. Mas o `Date` "não vem" com o fuso horário. É uma diferença sutil, porém importante, para entender como usá-lo.

Para ilustrar melhor, fiz o seguinte teste no Chrome, rodando no Windows (o comportamento pode não ser o mesmo em outros browsers e/ou sistemas operacionais):

- abra o console (pressione <kbd>F12</kbd>)
- crie uma data e imprima:

  ```
    let d = new Date();
    console.log(d);
  ```
- o resultado mostrará a data e hora atual, no fuso horário que está configurado no Windows
- entre nas configurações do Windows e mude o fuso horário (de preferência para lugares "distantes", como Europa ou Ásia, para que a diferença seja mais nítida)
- volte para o console do Chrome e só imprima a data novamente (sem criar uma nova): `console.log(d)`
- será mostrada a data e hora atual no novo fuso horário

Isso tudo sem mudar o objeto `Date`. Se ele "já viesse" com o fuso horário, a alteração no ambiente não afetaria a saída. Mas o `Date` não guarda a informação do fuso horário, ele só usa o fuso que está configurado no ambiente, em determinados momentos (por exemplo, quando a data é impressa no console), para converter o timestamp para os respectivos valores de data e hora.

Já testando no Firefox, o comportamento foi diferente: ele carrega o fuso horário do SO no momento em que se inicia e depois não atualiza mais. Ou seja, eu crio uma data e ela é mostrada no fuso que está configurado. Se eu mudar o fuso, não adianta nem criar novas instâncias de `Date`, que elas serão mostradas no fuso que estava configurado no momento em que o browser foi iniciado (e só reiniciando o browser para ele pegar a nova configuração).

---

E isso porque só testamos em 2 browsers diferentes. Mas se testarmos no Node, por exemplo, é possível sobrescrever o fuso horário de várias maneiras:

- no Linux, você pode setar a variável de ambiente `TZ` na linha de comando:

  ```
    TZ=Asia/Tokyo node teste.js
  ```
- ou no próprio arquivo JS, mudar o `process.env.TZ`. Ex: `process.env.TZ = 'Asia/Tokyo'` - isso sobrescreve a variável `TZ` e qualquer configuração do SO.

Por exemplo, o código abaixo:

```
d = new Date();

process.env.TZ = 'Europe/Berlin';
console.log(d.toString());
console.log(d.getHours());

process.env.TZ = 'Pacific/Apia';
console.log(d.toString());
console.log(d.getHours());
```

Rodando no Node (a partir da versão 13, se não me engano, pois [antes só funcionava se a variável fosse setada no início do script](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3286), e mudanças no meio do script não eram efetivadas), a saída é (rodando às 09:06 do dia 10/06/2020, Horário de Brasília):

```
Wed Jun 10 2020 14:06:18 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
14
Thu Jun 11 2020 01:06:18 GMT+1300 (Apia Standard Time)
1
```

<sup>Obs: o código acima foi testado no Linux, pois setar `process.env.TZ` não funcionou no Node do Windows</sup>

Ou seja, o mesmo objeto `Date` resulta em datas e horas diferentes, dependendo do fuso horário que está configurado **no momento em que `toString()` e `getHours()` são chamados**. Se o `Date` "já viesse" com o fuso horário, ele não seria afetado por esta mudança de configuração.

---

Se quer que a data e hora sejam **específicas de um fuso horário**, independente da configuração do ambiente, infelizmente o JavaScript não fornece muitas alternativas. O máximo que temos é [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString), que pode receber um timezone:

```
d.toLocaleString('en', { timeZone: 'America/Sao_Paulo' });
```

Assim, a data e hora sempre levarão em conta o timezone indicado, independente do que estiver configurado no ambiente. Mas o problema é que o formato sempre será dependente do *locale* (o primeiro parâmetro, que você pode trocar de `en` para `pt-BR`, por exemplo, se quiser o formato de datas brasileiro). Mas se você quiser somente o dia, ou somente a hora, não adianta usar os *getters*, pois eles estão limitados ao fuso configurado no ambiente.

Outra alternativa é usar uma biblioteca externa, como por exemplo o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). Para trabalhar com fusos horários, você também vai precisar do [Moment Timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/). Assim, você pode criar datas referentes a qualquer timezone, sem ser afetado pela configuração do ambiente. Em Node, por exemplo, ficaria assim:

```
let moment = require('moment-timezone');
let d = moment.tz('America/Sao_Paulo');

// mudar a configuração de timezone não afeta o Moment
process.env.TZ = 'Europe/Berlin';
console.log(d.format());
console.log(d.hour());

// mudar a configuração de timezone não afeta o Moment
process.env.TZ = 'Pacific/Apia';
console.log(d.format());
console.log(d.hour());

// converter para outro timezone
d.tz('Europe/Berlin');
console.log(d.format());
console.log(d.hour());
```

Assim, o `moment` criado preserva a informação do timezone (ele sim "já vem" com o timezone que é informado no momento em que é construído), e as alterações no ambiente não afetam a sua data e hora. Somente ao fazer uma conversão explícita para outro timezone, os valores de data e hora são atualizados. A saída do código acima é (rodado às 09:16 do dia 10/06/2020, Horário de Brasília):

```
2020-06-10T09:16:18-03:00
9
2020-06-10T09:16:18-03:00
9
2020-06-10T14:16:18+02:00
14
```

Se quiser usar o timezone configurado no ambiente, basta chamar `moment.tz()` sem parâmetros. Também dá para obter o possível timezone do ambiente usando [`moment.tz.guess()`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/) (sim, o nome é esse mesmo, "adivinhar" - leia o link da documentação para entender porque nem sempre é possível ter certeza e por isso ele tenta adivinhar o timezone do ambiente).

E se você precisar do `Date`, é possível converter, fazendo [`d.toDate()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) - só lembrando que, como isso retorna um `Date`, toda a informação do timezone é perdida.

---

Vale lembrar ainda que a outra afirmação feita na resposta já citada também não é 100% verdade: o fato de que o Horário de Brasília sempre estará 3 horas atrás de UTC. Isso vale a maior parte do tempo, mas durante o horário de verão, ele muda de UTC-3 para UTC-2. Tudo bem que atualmente (2020) não temos horário de verão no Brasil, mas como ele é definido pelo governo e políticos mudam de ideia a toda hora (nem sempre com motivações técnicas), nada garante que não voltará no futuro. Então não conte com isso (que sempre será -3).

Essa é outra vantagem de usar uma API dedicada como o Moment.js, pois ela possui todo o histórico de alterações, e ao usar timezones como `America/Sao_Paulo`, ela sempre buscará os valores corretos (desde que esteja atualizada, claro, pois como já disse, esses dados [mudam o tempo todo](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/)). Claro que se o seu sistema estiver atualizado, o browser também terá as informações corretas ao exibir a data. Usar uma lib externa depende mais do que você precisa (se não quer depender das configurações do ambiente, por exemplo, pode valer a pena).

De qualquer forma, perceba que "pegar a data do computador" já não parece mais tão simples quanto você imaginava. A própria "data do computador" depende do que está configurado no SO, e mesmo assim vimos que é possível sobrescrever essa configuração. Tudo depende do que você precisa, mas de qualquer forma as alternativas estão aí, escolha a que for mais adequada para o seu caso.

---

Veja mais sobre o assunto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/344030/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/455444/112052).

Comment: Cara muito bom, explicou tudo oq precisava e até mais! Muito obrigado! Melhor explicação

Answer (score 4):

A data já vem no fuso horário que o dispositivo está configurado. Se ele estiver configurado para o horário de Brasília, por exemplo, será UTC (*Coordinated Universal Time*) -3 horas.

Para pegar ano, mês, dia, hora, minuto e segundo você usa o objeto `new Date()`:

```js
var hoje = new Date();
var ano = hoje.getFullYear();
var mes = hoje.getMonth();
var dia = hoje.getDate();
var hora = hoje.getHours();
var minuto = hoje.getMinutes();
var segundo = hoje.getSeconds();

console.log("Ano:",ano+", Mês:",mes+", Dia:",dia+", Hora:",hora+", Minuto:",minuto+", Segundo:",segundo);
```

> **Lembrando que o valor do mês inicia em 0 (janeiro é 0, fevereiro é 1, março é 2 etc.).** Se quiser pegar o valor do mês no calendário, é preciso somar `+1`:

```
var mes = hoje.getMonth()+1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a função Date:

```js
var date = new Date();

console.log(date);
```

para mais especificações, leia a documentação:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date