# Como converter /Date(1533524400000-0300)/ para PHP

Tags: php, json, datetime, timestamp

Recebo como retorno de um JSON a data neste formato:

```
/Date(1533524400000-0300)/
```

Como conveter para um `DateTime` em PHP?

Comment: Mas isso é uma data mesmo? Qual o tipo dessa data?

Comment: @DiegoSouza Não sei se há um nome oficial, mas este formato é chamado de [*Microsoft JSON date*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/206384) (talvez porque a MS tenha escolhido usar este formato em suas APIs de JSON). No caso, `1533524400000` é o unix timestamp em milissegundos, e `-0300` é o offset (neste caso, 3 horas antes de UTC). Na minha opinião, um dos piores formatos de data já criados...

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de não haver um nome oficial, este formato é conhecido como [Microsoft JSON Date](https://davidsekar.com/javascript/converting-json-date-string-date-to-date-object), já que algumas versões mais antigas do Framework .NET serializavam datas neste formato.

É importante salientar que ele **não** faz parte da [especificação oficial do formato JSON](http://json.org/). Ele é simplesmente uma string, que contém dados em um formato arbitrário. Este valor pode vir como `/Date(1533524400000-0300)/` ou `/Date(1533524400000)/`.

O número gigante (`1533524400000`) é um timestamp, explicado em detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) e [aqui](https://hkotsubo.github.io/blog/2019-05-02/o-que-e-timestamp). Mas resumindo, ele representa um único instante, um ponto na linha do tempo.

O detalhe é que ele pode representar uma data e hora diferente em cada parte do mundo, dependendo do fuso horário. No caso, também temos a informação do *offset*: `-0300`, que indica 3 horas a menos com relação a [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), então basta extrair ambas as informações e montar o objeto `DateTime`:

```php
if (preg_match('/Date\((\d+)([-+]\d{4})?\)/', '/Date(1533524400000-0300)/', $matches)) {
    $timestamp = number_format($matches[1] / 1000, 3, '.', '');
    // $matches pode ter até 3 elementos: o match total e os dois grupos de captura
    if (count($matches) === 3) {
        $offset = $matches[2]; // se tem offset, pega
    } else {
        $offset = '+0000'; // se não tem offset, assume que é zero
    }
    $data = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', $timestamp);
    $data->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($offset));
    var_dump($data);
}
```

Saída:

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2018-08-06 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "-03:00"
}
```

Claro que uma vez tendo a data, você pode formatá-la da maneira que achar melhor. Por exemplo, `echo $data->format('d/m/Y');` para que fique `06/08/2018`, etc - consulte a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) para mais detalhes.

---

A solução da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/305478/112052) nem sempre dará dia 6 de agosto, pois ela usa a [função `date`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date), que por baixo dos panos usa o timezone *default* que estiver configurado no ambiente, e ignora completamente o *offset*. Por exemplo, se o timezone *default* for `America/Los_Angeles`, o resultado da outra resposta será dia 5 de agosto.

Mas no meu entendimento, o *offset* deve ser levado em conta, ou seja, neste caso a resposta deveria ser sempre 6 de agosto, independente do timezone *default*.

Answer (score -1):

Use essa função que encontrei no SOen:

```php
echo parseJsonDate('/Date(1533524400000-0300)/', 'date');

function parseJsonDate($date, $type = 'date') {
    preg_match( '/\/Date\((\d+)([+-]\d{4})\)/', $date, $matches); // Match the time stamp (microtime) and the timezone offset (may be + or -)
    $date = date( 'm-d-Y', $matches[1]/1000 ); // convert to seconds from microseconds
    switch($type){    
        case 'date':
            return $date; // returns '05-04-2012'
            break;

        case 'array':
            return explode('-', $date); // return array('05', '04', '2012')
            break;

        case 'string':
            return $matches[1] . $matches[2]; // returns 1336197600000-0600
            break;
    }
}
```

Saída:

```
08-06-2018
```