# Converter data dd-mm-aa para aaaa-mm-dd em Java

Tags: java, string, data

Estou recebendo via formulário:

```
28-set-2018
```

e preciso salvar no banco

```
2019-09-29 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende: o campo no banco de dados está como string (varchar)?

Pois geralmente datas são salvas nos bancos de dados em um campo com o tipo específico (date, datetime, timestamp, etc). Se esse for o caso, não deveria haver preocupação quanto ao formato salvo.

A sua preocupação, neste caso, seria apenas converter a string `28-set-2018` para uma data e salvá-la diretamente no banco.

Se você está usando Java >= 8, pode usar a [API `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html):

```
Locale locale = new Locale("pt", "BR");
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-uuuu", locale);
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("28-set-2018", parser);
```

O `java.util.Locale` é importante porque o mês está em Português, e se você não informá-lo, será usado o locale *default* da JVM (que pode ser outro idioma), então é melhor usar o locale correto.

O problema é que [somente a partir do JDBC 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43039614) é possível salvar as classes do `java.time` diretamente no banco, [usando `setObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setObject-int-java.lang.Object-):

```
preparedStatement.setObject(1, date);
```

Verifique se o driver do banco de dados que você está usando já é compatível com JDBC 4.2. E caso seja, verifique o respectivo tipo do campo, pois no `java.time` há várias classes diferentes para representar datas e horas ([exemplo no PostreSQL](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html) - veja se e como o seu banco está mapeando estes tipos).

No seu caso, como você está querendo salvar também o horário, então você precisa de um `LocalDateTime` com o horário setado para meia-noite (as duas formas abaixo são equivalentes):

```
// use atStartOfDay (seta horário para meia-noite)
LocalDateTime datetime = date.atStartOfDay();

// Ou passe o valor do horário explicitamente
LocalDateTime datetime = date.atTime(0, 0);
```

Neste caso, passe o `LocalDateTime` para `setObject`. Caso precise de outros tipos (como `ZonedDateTime`, que também considera o fuso-horário), consulte [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/112052) que tem mais detalhes sobre o `java.time` e seus tipos. Veja também o [tutorial da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Digo isso porque datas não tem formato. Elas só possuem valores (dia, mês, ano, etc). Quando um tipo date, datetime, timestamp, etc, é salvo no banco, esses valores é que são salvos. Os formatos servem apenas para visualizar os valores de uma maneira inteligível: as strings `28-set-2018` e `2018-09-28` são apenas representações (formatos) diferentes para o mesmo valor (a mesma data).

---

Mas se você precisa de uma `String` naquele formato específico (e não um date, datetime, etc), basta criar outro `DateTimeFormatter`:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String dataFormatada = datetime.format(fmt); // 2018-09-28 00:00:00
```

Atenção quanto a [diferença entre `H` e `h`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns): o maiúsculo representa as horas do dia (valores de 0 a 23) e o minúsculo representa a "hora AM/PM" (valores de 1 a 12) - veja diferença [aqui](https://ideone.com/1yCkFc). Ou seja, meia-noite será impresso como `00:00:00` se usar `HH:mm:ss`, e como `12:00:00` se usar `hh:mm:ss` (já que meia-noite também pode ser escrito como 12 AM).

---

Se o seu driver não é compatível com JDBC 4.2, não tem jeito, você deve gravar um `java.sql.Date`. Neste caso, basta converter o `LocalDate` que obtivemos acima:

```
import java.sql.Date;

// valueOf fica em java.sql.Date, não confundir com java.util.Date
Date sqlDate = Date.valueOf(date);
```

Mas no seu caso, como você precisa do horário, então converta o `LocalDateTime` para um `java.sql.Timestamp`:

```
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(datetime);
```

Aí você pode salvar estes objetos diretamente no banco, usando os métodos específicos ([`setDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate-int-java.sql.Date-), [`setTimestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp-int-java.sql.Timestamp-), etc).

*Lembrando que estas classes pegam a data/hora no timezone default da JVM e convertem para um [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) (que é o valor guardado internamente por estas classes).*

---

#### Java <= 7

Para Java <= 7, você pode usar o [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), que possui praticamente as mesmas funcionalidades do `java.time`. A diferença é que elas estão no pacote `org.threeten.bp`, mas os nomes e métodos são os mesmos.

Outra diferença é a forma de converter para `java.sql.Date` e `java.sql.Timestamp`. Como os métodos `valueOf(LocalDate)` e `valueOf(LocalDateTime)` só foram adicionados no Java 8, o backport criou a classe `org.threeten.bp.DateTimeUtils` para fazer as conversões (veja [na documentação](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DateTimeUtils.html)).

---

#### Não tenho Java 8 e não quero usar outra API

Neste caso, o jeito é usar um `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` para gerar um `java.util.Date`, e em seguida usar `java.util.Calendar` para setar o horário para meia-noite:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("pt", "BR");
SimpleDateFormat sdfInput = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", locale);
// converter String para java.util.Date
Date data = sdfInput.parse("28-set-2018");

// setar horário para meia-noite
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(data);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

// obter o novo valor do java.util.Date (com horário igual a meia-noite)
data = cal.getTime();

// criar java.sql.Date ou java.sql.Timestamp
java.sql.Date d = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Novamente: se o campo no banco de dados é uma data (o tipo é date, datetime, timestamp, etc), salve o `java.util.Date`/`java.sql.Date`/`java.sql.Timestamp` diretamente. Mas caso você precise de uma string em outro formato, basta criar outro `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfOutput = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String dataFormatada = sdfOutput.format(cal.getTime()); // 2018-09-28 00:00:00
```

OBS: neste caso específico, setar a data para meia-noite não seria necessário, pois `SimpleDateFormat` já faz isso quando os campos de horário não estão presentes. De qualquer forma, deixo o código como referência caso você precise mudar para outros valores.

---

#### Observação quanto ao nome do mês

Muitas informações de localização [foram alteradas no JDK 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/enhancements.8.html#cldr) e [no JDK 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-A20F2989-BFA9-482D-8618-6CBB4BAAE310), conforme discutido [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46245412).

E para o JDK 11, também foram feitas mais alterações referentes à localização. Ou seja, pode ser que, dependendo do locale, as `Strings` resultantes sejam diferentes – os detalhes podem ser encontrados no [OpenJDK Bug System](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8202537).

Isso significa que, dependendo da versão do Java, *pode ser* que ele não consiga interpretar o mês com letra minúscula (`set`). Neste caso, basta criar um `DateTimeFormatter` *case insensitive*:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("pt", "BR");
DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .appendPattern("dd-MMM-uuuu")
    .toFormatter(locale);
```

---

E ainda há uma outra alternativa, caso o horário deva ser sempre meia-noite. Você pode usar o método `parseDefaulting` para setar valores predefinidos para o horário, caso este não esteja presente na `String` de entrada. Basta passar um [`java.time.temporal.ChronoField`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html) correspondente ao campo e o respectivo valor:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .appendPattern("dd-MMM-uuuu")
    // setar hora e minuto para zero
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
    .toFormatter(new Locale("pt", "BR"));
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse("28-set-2018", parser);
```

Ao setar hora e minuto para zero, os segundos e frações de segundo também serão setados automaticamente para zero (caso o horário não esteja na entrada).

Com isso, você pode fazer o parsing diretamente para `LocalDateTime`. Como a `String` só possui dia, mês e ano, o horário será setado automaticamente para meia-noite e a partir daí você usa a data como precisar.

Answer (score 0):

Algo assim deve funcionar, só se atente com relação ao mes da sua data.. ele deve estar com a abreviação em inglês (jan, feb, mar, apr, may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatterInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy");
DateTimeFormatter formatterOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");

//entrada
String date = "28-set-2018";

//criando objeto data a partir da sua string
LocalDateTime localDate = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter);

//saída 2019-09-29 00:00:00
localDate.format(formatterOutput);
```

Se quiser usar os meses em português, use:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("pt", "BR");
DateTimeFormatter formatterInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy", locale);
```

Comment: eu obtenho as datas tipo cell e converto para String

Comment: String date = row.getCell(5);

Comment: Se a entrada só tem dia, mês e ano, fazer um `parse` diretamente para um `LocalDateTime` [**dará erro**](https://repl.it/repls/HastyDrearyMetadata). Outro detalhe é que `hh` imprime meia-noite como `12` - para ter `00`, use `HH`- veja [aqui](https://ideone.com/1yCkFc). E *"deve estar com a abreviação em inglês"* só é válido se o locale *default* da JVM for inglês. No meu caso o *default* é pt_BR e funciona sem precisar setar o locale (apesar de ser recomendado setar um específico para não depender da configuração *default* da JVM)