# Erro: "java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2018-11-14T12:12"

Tags: java, mysql, java-ee, datetime

Tenho a seguinte interface de inserção de dados:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os comentários abaixo representam as tentativas de correção do erro mas nenhuma funcionou.

No HTML o `type` é `datetime-local`, no banco o tipo foi criado como datetime e na classe `ControladoraJPA` criada pelo java diretamente conectado com a tabela no banco, o atributo veio apenas como `Date`.

Tenho o seguinte método java:

```
public void cadastrarPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException{
    try{
        String conteudo = request.getParameter("content_post");
        String data_cria = request.getParameter("data_criacao");
        String data_public = request.getParameter("data_publicacao");
        String categoria = request.getParameter("categoria");

        //data_cria = data_cria.replace('T', ' ').concat(":00");;
        //data_public = data_cria.replace('T', ' ').concat(":00");

        //DateTimeFormatter formato = DateTimeFormatter.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
        //Date date = (Date) formato.parse(data_cria);
        //Date date2 = (Date) formato.parse(data_public);
        //java.sql.Timestamp data1 = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(data_cria);
        //java.sql.Timestamp data2 = java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(data_public);

        //DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
        //Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(data_cria);
        //Date date2 = (Date)formatter.parse(data_public);

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PROJETO_POSTPU");
        UserJpaController userJpa = new UserJpaController(emf);
        PostJpaController postJpa = new PostJpaController(emf);
        CategoryJpaController categoryJpa = new CategoryJpaController(emf);

        List<Category> listCat = new ArrayList();
        listCat = categoryJpa.findCategoryEntities();
        List<User> listUser = new ArrayList();
        listUser = userJpa.findUserEntities();

        Post post = new Post();
        post.setContent(conteudo);
        post.setCreatedAt(date);
        post.setPublishedAt(date2);
        for(Category c : listCat){
            if(c.getDescription().equals(categoria)){
                post.setIdCategory(c);
                break;
            } else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        for(User u : listUser){
            if(u.getUsername() == userSec){
                post.setIdAuthor(u);
            }
        }
        postJpa.create(post);

        //request.setAttribute("resp", result);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/feed/feed.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Não seria algo como `DateTimeFormatter.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd\THH:mm")`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Na verdade é `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm` ([ou ainda `uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41178418)). Se bem que, para o formato ISO 8601, nem precisa de um `DateTimeFormatter` (se for usar o java.time, claro, pois para `Date` e `SimpleDateFormat` precisa), veja [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/343328/112052) abaixo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) faz parte da API [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), que foi introduzida no Java 8 e é incompatível com a antiga API (apesar de ser possível converter entre as APIs, mais sobre isso abaixo). Se você olhar a [documentação do método `parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-), verá que ele retorna um [`TemporalAccessor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html). Este tipo é incompatível com [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), por isso o *cast* não funciona.

Já a sua tentativa com `SimpleDateFormat` não funciona porque o formato usado (`"MM/dd/yy"`) não corresponde à `String` que você quer transformar em data (`"2018-11-14T12:12"`).

Para resolver com `SimpleDateFormat`, basta informar o formato correto:

```
String data = "2018-11-14T12:12";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
// java.util.Date
Date date = sdf.parse(data);
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
```

Para saber mais sobre o formato, veja a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Não precisa trocar a letra `T` por espaço, basta colocá-la entre aspas simples (`'T'`) **no construtor** de `SimpleDateFormat`, que ele entenderá que ela deve ser interpretada literalmente como a própria letra "T".

Também não precisa adicionar `:00` no final da sua string, para representar os segundos, pois se eles forem omitidos, seu valor é automaticamente setado para zero.

Lembrando que o método `parse` retorna um [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html). Se você estiver usando [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html), aí é um pouco mais complicado. A [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) diz que o valor do timestamp deve ser "normalizado", setando-se os campos de horário para zero. Para isso podemos usar a classe [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html):

```
String data = "2018-11-14T12:12";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm");
java.util.Date date = sdf.parse(data);

// setar os campos de horário para zero
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
// criar o java.sql.Date
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Como a string de entrada não possui os segundos e milissegundos, eles já estarão setados para zero. Por isso eu só precisei setar as horas e minutos.

---

Mas se você tem o Java 8 disponível, pode usar a nova API também.

A string `2018-11-14T12:12` está no formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), então você nem precisa de um `DateTimeFormatter` para fazer o parsing. A diferença é que no `java.time` há [vários tipos diferentes de data](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html) e você deve escolher a classe adequada para tratar seus dados.

No caso, a string contém data e hora, então o tipo mais indicado é [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html):

```
String data = "2018-11-14T12:12";
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(data);
```

Mas como converter para `Date`? Primeiro precisamos entender o que cada classe representa.

`java.util.Date` representa um ponto na linha do tempo, um [timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Um valor que corresponde à quantidade de milissegundos que se passaram desde o *Unix Epoch* - sendo que o *Unix Epoch* é `1970-01-01T00:00Z` (1 de janeiro de 1970, meia-noite, [**em UTC**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)).

Isso quer dizer que o `Date` representa uma data e hora diferentes, dependendo de onde você está. Neste exato momento, se eu rodar `new Date().getTime()`, terei o valor do timestamp igual a `1542192713069`. Qualquer computador, em qualquer lugar do mundo, que rodasse isso no mesmo instante que eu, teria o mesmo valor.

Só que este mesmo valor de timestamp corresponde a uma data e hora diferentes em cada lugar do mundo:

- Em São Paulo: 14 de novembro de 2018 às 08:51:53.069
- Em Tóquio: 14 de novembro de 2018 às 19:51:53.069
- Em Samoa: **13** de novembro de 2018 às 23:51:53.069

Ou seja, o `Date` representa apenas o timestamp `1542192713069`, mas para [traduzir este valor para uma data e hora](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052), precisamos saber o timezone (fuso-horário).

Já `java.time.LocalDateTime` representa uma data e horário, mas sem qualquer noção de timezone. Portanto, converter um `LocalDateTime` para `Date` pode resultar em um timestamp diferente, dependendo do timezone escolhido.

`SimpleDateFormat` usa o timezone *default* da JVM (a menos que você configure outro, usando `setTimeZone()`), então você pode simular este comportamento usando [`ZoneId.systemDefault()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--). Em seguida, basta converter para `Date` ou `Timestamp`, dependendo do que você precisa:

```
String data = "2018-11-14T12:12";
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(data);
// converter para timezone default e em seguida para java.util.Date
java.util.Date date = Date.from(dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());

// ou converta diretamente para Timestamp
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.from(dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
```

No caso de `Timestamp`, você também pode passar o `LocalDateTime` diretamente. Neste caso, o timezone *default* da JVM será usado internamente:

```
// passar o LocalDateTime diretamente
Timestamp ts = Timestamp.valueOf(dateTime);
```

E se precisar criar um `java.sql.Date`:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf(dateTime.toLocalDate());
```

---

Caso o banco que você está usando tenha um driver compatível com o **JDBC 4.2** e seja possível alterar os campos de data, é possível trabalhar diretamente com o `java.time`, usando os métodos `setObject` da classe [`java.sql.PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) e `getObject` da classe [`java.sql.ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html):

```
LocalDateTime dateTime = ...

PreparedStatement ps = ...
// seta o java.time.LocalDateTime
ps.setObject(1, dateTime);

// obter o LocalDateTime do banco
ResultSet rs = ...
LocalDateTime instant = rs.getObject(1, LocalDateTime.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro você deve formatar sua data, algo como:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Esse erro ocorre, quando o tipo da data que você está tentando passar não é o esperado