# Comparando datetime com intervalo de minutos

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, data, comparação

Preciso comparar 2 datas, essas datas estão no formato `%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S` e uma é obtida através da internet, e a outra localmente, porém não estou conseguindo fazer a comparação das duas com um intervalo de 2 minutos, em que em até 2 minutos de diferença, deve retornar verdadeiro em uma condição.

Código:

```
import time, os
import ntplib
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
client = ntplib.NTPClient()
response = client.request('pool.ntp.org')
webtime = time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S',time.localtime(response.tx_time))
print(webtime)

data_e_hora_atuais = datetime.now()
fuso_horario = timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')
data_e_hora_sao_paulo = data_e_hora_atuais.astimezone(fuso_horario)
localtime = data_e_hora_sao_paulo.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
print(localtime)
```

Como eu poderia fazer isso, com um intervalo de 2 minutos entre as datas obtidas localmente e da web?

Comment: Você quer que retorne verdadeiro se a diferença entre uma "datetime" e outra for menor, ou igual a 2 minutos, correto?

Comment: Sim @GustavoSampaio

Comment: É necessário comparar apenas com datas do jeito humano (dia, mês, ano etc)? Parece bem mais simples trabalhar somente com somente em segundos.

Comment: Não é necessário comparar as dadas do jeito humano, contanto que sejam comparadas tudo bem.

Comment: @GiovanniNunes De fato, neste caso parece mais fácil trabalhar com os valores em segundos do que criar datas. De qualquer forma, deixei as 2 opções abaixo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Formato das datas

Para gerar as variáveis `webtime` e `localtime`, você está usando respectivamente [`time.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.strftime) e [`datetime.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime), que são 2 métodos que retornam **`strings`**, e não datas.

**Datas e horas não têm formato**. Uma data é simplesmente um valor (na verdade um conjunto de valores: dia, mês e ano) que representa um ponto específico no calendário, e um horário é outro conjunto de valores (hora, minuto, segundo, frações de segundo) que representa um momento específico de um dia.

Esses valores podem ser representados de várias formas diferentes. Por exemplo, a data de "1 de fevereiro de 2018" possui 3 valores: dia 1, mês 2 e ano 2018. Mas esta mesma data pode ser representada de várias maneiras diferentes:

- 01/02/2018 - formato comum em vários países
- 1 de fevereiro de 2018 - em bom português
- 2018-02-01 - formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- Feb 1<sup>st</sup>, 2018 - formato comum nos EUA
- 2018年2月1日 - em [japonês](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=pt&tl=ja&text=1%20de%20fevereiro%20de%202018)

Embora todos esses formatos (todas essas strings) sejam diferentes, **todos eles representam a mesma data**.

Sendo assim, se você quer calcular a diferença entre duas datas, não transforme-as em strings (só faça isso se você quiser mostrar a data em um formato específico). Para fazer cálculos e outras manipulações com as datas, use-as diretamente - e no seu caso, como já está usando o [módulo `datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), use os tipos que ele oferece.

---

### Diferença entre datas

Para calcular a diferença entre as datas, primeiro precisamos obtê-las como um [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime).

Vi que você está usando [`time.localtime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.localtime). Este método recebe um [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) em segundos (a quantidade de segundos desde o [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) e converte para a data e hora "local" (ou seja, o dia e horário correspondente no timezone da máquina onde o código estiver rodando).

Mas depois você obtém a data atual em um timezone específico (`America/Sao_Paulo`), então eu sugiro que ambas as datas estejam no mesmo timezone para que possamos compará-las.

Usando `datetime`, você pode converter o timestamp para uma data e hora em um timezone específico, usando [`datetime.fromtimestamp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) (passando o timestamp e o timezone), e pode obter a data/hora atual no mesmo timezone, usando [`datetime.now`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) e passando o timezone como parâmetro. Em seguida, pode subtrair os `datetimes` diretamente, obtendo um [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta):

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

fuso_horario = timezone('America/Sao_Paulo')

# usando o timestamp e o fuso horário
webdate = datetime.fromtimestamp(response.tx_time, tz=fuso_horario)

# data/hora atual no mesmo timezone usado acima
agora = datetime.now(tz=fuso_horario)

# diferença é um timedelta
diferenca = agora - webdate

# diferença maior ou igual a 2 minutos
if diferenca.total_seconds() >= 120:
    print("diferença maior ou igual a 2 minutos")
```

Na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) diz que se uma datas possui timezone e outra não, o cálculo da diferença entre elas lança um [`TypeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#TypeError). Por isso criei ambas com um timezone.

---

Obs: a partir do Python 3.9 você pode usar o [módulo `zoneinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html), cujo funcionamento é bem similar ao `pytz`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

fuso_horario = ZoneInfo('America/Sao_Paulo')

# usando o timestamp e o fuso horário
webdate = datetime.fromtimestamp(response.tx_time, tz=fuso_horario)
# data/hora atual no mesmo timezone usado acima
agora = datetime.now(tz=fuso_horario)

# diferença é um timedelta
diferenca = agora - webdate

# diferença maior ou igual a 2 minutos
if diferenca.total_seconds() >= 120:
    print("diferença maior ou igual a 2 minutos")
```

---

### Simplificando

Se bem que, no seu caso, como você recebe da web o valor do timestamp em segundos, basta obter o valor do timestamp atual (também em segundos) usando [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.time) e subtrair um do outro:

```
import time

# diferença, em segundos, entre o instante atual e o recebido da web
diferenca = time.time() - response.tx_time
if diferenca >= 120:
    print("diferença maior ou igual a 2 minutos")
```

O timestamp é um valor "universal" (é o mesmo no mundo todo, todos os computadores que rodarem `time.time()` no mesmo instante terão o mesmo resultado). Por isso eu nem preciso convertê-lo para uma data e hora em um timezone específico, já que só queremos saber a diferença entre eles.

Criar `datetimes` em um timezone específico será útil caso você precise manipular as datas depois (ou mostrá-las na tela, por exemplo, usando [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime)). Caso contrário, para este caso específico, me parece mais simples usar apenas os timestamps.

---

Não ficou claro se você quer saber se o valor da web está no passado ou futuro em relação à data atual. Se tanto faz, você pode obter o valor absoluto da diferença (sem o sinal) usando [`abs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs):

```
diferenca = abs(time.time() - response.tx_time)
```

Ou, se for usar a solução acima com `timedelta`, faça `if abs(diferenca.total_seconds()) >= 120`.

Se quer saber somente se a data da web está no futuro (2 minutos depois da data atual), basta inverter e fazer `response.tx_time - time.time()` (e ver se é maior ou igual a 120).

Answer (score 2):

Se você deseja apenas comparar duas datas com uma determinada tolerância de tempo entre elas a melhor alternativa é trabalhar com elas em segundos e não com o formato humano co dia, mês, ano, hora, minuto etc.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time

from ntplib import NTPClient


TIME_GAP = 2 * 60 * 1000  # 2 minutos * 60


def get_internet_time(server="pool.ntp.org"):
    """ retorna a hora, via NTP, em segundos. """
    client = NTPClient()
    response = client.request(server)
    return response.tx_time


def check_times(first_time, second_time, gap=TIME_GAP):
    """ verifica datas em `first_time` e `second_time` aplicando uma
    tolerância de tempo `gap` entre elas. """
    return (first_time // gap) == (second_time // gap)


def main():
    """ função principal """
    internet_time = get_internet_time()
    local_time = time.time()
    wrong_time = local_time + TIME_GAP * 2

    print(internet_time, local_time, wrong_time)
    print(check_times(internet_time, local_time))
    print(check_times(internet_time, wrong_time))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Separei em funções pra ficar mais simples de entender mas toda a ideia é dividir os valores das duas datas em segundos pela tolerância desejada (a variável `TIME_GAP` neste caso). Se estiverem na faixa as datas podem ser consideradas iguais:

```
1544888407.6483665 1544888407.783229 1545128407.783229
True
False
```

No código de exemplo variável `wrong_time` é artificialmente inflada para mostrar a diferença. :)

(nota, na versão original fiz confusão entre segundos e milissegundos, mas a versão acima já está corrigida).

Comment: sei que não está na questão, mas e no caso se eu quisesse verificar com 15 dias de intervalo, entre uma data e outra, retornado `True` se estivesse dentro desses 15 dias, como eu faria? Tentei utilizando `os.path.getctime("project.exe")` porem não resultou no esperado, retornando sempre `True`. Utilizei `TIME_GAP_DAYS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 15` ficando `print(check_times(local_time, os.path.getctime("project.exe"), gap=TIME_GAP_DAYS))` Agradeço se puder sanar essa dúvida.

Comment: Também fiquei curioso mas após pensar um pouco me dei conta de que o que escrevi já respondia, tem de tirar o 1000 pois se está trabalhando com segundos e não milissegundos (só colocar o áudio do Chaves dizendo "que burro, dá zero pra ele!" aqui).

Comment: Aliás, achei uma solução até mais elegante para fazer a verificação de datas, o timehash -- https://github.com/abeusher/timehash