# Retornar data invertida em PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Estou elaborando um relatório com base na data-inicial (`start_date`) e data-final (`end_date`).

Meu retorno de `filter` vem através do POST, se eu usar então `print_r($_POST)`, noto que a data vem no padrão brasileiro, normal.

```
$start_date = ($filter['start_date']) ? date("Y-m-d", strtotime($filter['start_date'])) : null;
$end_date = ($filter['end_date']) ? date("Y-m-d", strtotime($filter['end_date'])) : null;
```

Ao usar `strtotime()` para inverter a data, somente a `start_date` dá certo.

```
`start_date` : 2019-01-12
`end_date` : 1970-01-01
```

Resultado o `print_r($_POST);`

```
Array
(
    [start_date] => 12/01/2019
    [end_date] => 26/01/2019
)
```

> Obs.: Notei que se eu digitar `13/01/2019`, o retorno será `1970-01-01`. Então, isto acontece por conta da inversão, qual seria a maneira correta de fazer isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação de `strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes), quando a string passada está usando `/` como separador, assume-se que ela está no formato `m/d/y` (mês/dia/ano).

No caso do `start_date`, o valor é `12/01/2019`, e por isso é interpretado como "1 de dezembro de 2019" (e não 12 de janeiro). Tanto que, testando seu código com esta string, [eu obtive `"2019-12-01"`](https://ideone.com/srUMEv) (não sei como você obteve `2019-01-12`, mas enfim).

Já no caso de `end_date`, o valor é `26/01/2019`, e `strtotime` interpretará como "o dia 1 do mês 26", o que resulta em uma data inválida. Neste caso, [`strtotime` retorna `FALSE`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-returnvalues).

O problema é que, ao passar o `FALSE` para a função `date`, este valor é [interpretado como o número **zero**](https://ideone.com/slE9ja) (já que [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) espera um `int` como parâmetro).

E como este parâmetro é o valor do [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) (ou seja, a quantidade de segundos desde 01/01/1970), o timestamp com valor zero [acaba resultando em `1970-01-01`](https://ideone.com/B70YEE).

---

Uma maneira de resolver é trocar `strtotime` por [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), especificando em qual formato está a string (no caso, `d/m/Y`). Este método retorna um [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), que por sua vez possui o método [`format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php), que pode ser usado para obter uma string contendo a data em outro formato (substituindo `date()`):

```
// parsing da string, criando uma data
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", "26/01/2019");
// formatar a data (converter para outro formato)
echo ($date->format("Y-m-d")); // 2019-01-26
```

Veja este código funcionando no [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/tswsgc).