# Como verificar as datas no input type="datetime-local"?

Tags: javascript, data, datetime-local

Tenho uma página em HTML com um formulário de envio de data/hora de entrada e data/hora saída (`input datetime-local`).

Preciso verificar na mesma página se os campos foram preenchidos somente com as datas diferentes no momento em que o usuário clicar no botão `submit`.

```js
function validar() {
var dataHoraInicio = formInsere.dataHoraInicio.value;
var dataHoraFim    = formInsere.dataHoraFim.value;

if (dataHoraInicio == "") {
alert('Preencha o campo data hora entrada!');
formInsere.dataHoraInicio.focus();
return false;
}

if (dataHoraFim == "") {
alert('Preencha o campo data hora saida!');
formInsere.dataHoraInicio.focus();
return false;
}

}//fim function//
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<br>
<br>

<form id="formInsere" action="valida.php" name="formInsere" method="POST" >
             
    <label>&nbsp;Data hor&aacute;rio entrada<br>
            <input type="datetime-local" name="dataHoraInicio">
        </label>
        <br><br>
                <label>&nbsp;Data hor&aacute;rio sa&iacute;da<br>
                    <input type="datetime-local" name="dataHoraFim">
                </label><br>
                <br><br>
    
  <input type="submit"  onclick="return validar()">  
</form>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

A primeira coisa é entender que o [valor de um campo `datetime-local`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#Value) é uma string no formato [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). Exemplo:

```js
function validar(evt) {
  let dataHoraInicio = document.querySelector('#formInsere').dataHoraInicio.value;
  console.log(dataHoraInicio);
  console.log(typeof dataHoraInicio); // string
  evt.preventDefault();
}

document.querySelector('#formInsere').addEventListener('submit', validar);
```

```html
<form id="formInsere" name="formInsere" method="POST" >
  <input type="datetime-local" name="dataHoraInicio">
  <input type="submit">     
</form>
```

Colocando a data de "15 de março de 2019, às 10:30", a variável `dataHoraInicio` terá o valor igual a `2019-03-15T10:30`. Qualquer data que você colocar terá o seu `value` nesse formato ("aaaa-mm-ddThh:mm").

Felizmente a [classe `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Parameters) do JavaScript [reconhece esse formato](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse#Date_Time_String_Format), então basta você passar este valor para o construtor, e em seguida verificar se o dia, mês e ano são os mesmos.

Pelo que entendi, o formulário não deve ser submetido se a data (dia, mês e ano) for igual, independente dos horários escolhidos. Sendo assim, basta comparar o dia, mês e ano:

```js
let formulario = document.querySelector('#formInsere');

function validar(evt) {
  let dataHoraInicio = formulario.dataHoraInicio.value;
  let dataHoraFim    = formulario.dataHoraFim.value;
  if (dataHoraInicio == "") {
    alert('Preencha o campo data hora entrada!');
    formulario.dataHoraInicio.focus();
    evt.preventDefault();
  } else if (dataHoraFim == "") {
    alert('Preencha o campo data hora saida!');
    formulario.dataHoraInicio.focus();
    evt.preventDefault();
  } else {
    // cria as datas
    let dtInicio = new Date(dataHoraInicio);
    let dtFim = new Date(dataHoraFim);
    // verifica se o dia, mês e ano são iguais
    if (dtInicio.getDate() === dtFim.getDate()
        && dtInicio.getMonth() === dtFim.getMonth()
        && dtInicio.getFullYear() === dtFim.getFullYear()) {
      alert('As datas não podem estar no mesmo dia');
      evt.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}

formulario.addEventListener('submit', validar);
```

```html
<form id="formInsere" name="formInsere" method="POST">
    <label>&nbsp;Data hor&aacute;rio entrada</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="dataHoraInicio"><br>
    <label>&nbsp;Data hor&aacute;rio sa&iacute;da</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" name="dataHoraFim"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

A comparação acima considera apenas o dia ([`getDate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate)), mês ([`getMonth()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth)) e ano ([`getFullYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setFullYear)). Atenção para não usar erroneamente os métodos [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) (que retorna o dia da semana, e não o dia do mês) e [`getYear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getYear) (que além de estar *deprecated*, retorna o ano indexado em 1900 - ou seja, 2019 é retornado como 119).

Se quiser comparar tanto a data quanto a hora, basta trocar o `if` por:

```
if (dtInicio.getTime() === dtFim.getTime()) {
    // datas são iguais (tanto o dia/mês/ano quanto o horário)
}
```

[`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) retorna o valor do [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) (o número de milissegundos desde o [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)), e é o modo mais direto de verificar se as datas correspondem exatamente ao mesmo instante.

---

Lembrando que [alguns *browsers* não suportam](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#Handling_browser_support) o `input type=datetime-local`, mas [a documentação descreve meios de contornar esta limitação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Handling_browser_support).

Comment: Ok, estou ciente que alguns browsers não suportam!

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @PhelipeMachado Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode optar por aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. E quando tiver 15 pontos  [**vc também poderá votar**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) em todas as respostas que achou úteis.

Comment: Amigo, no caso para que  as datas não sejam  sejam diferentes, ex: data hora inicio 04-04-2019 07:00  data hora fim 04-04-2019 17:00  como ficaria a validação? Pois eu mudei o operador === para != e não funcionou!  Poderia me ajudar, por favor!?

Comment: Sugiro que edite a pergunta e coloque o código, pois assim fica mais fácil descobrir o problema

Comment: @PhelipeMachado A princípio deveria funcionar. Se está fazendo `===` e mudou para `!==`, não tem porque dar erro. Por isso sugeri que [**edite**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/365780/edit) a pergunta e coloque o código, pois só com "não funcionou" não dá para saber o que está acontecendo de errado