# Qual o tipo de dados para armazenar "2019-02-06T14:14:38+00:00"?

Tags: php, mysql, string, datetime, timestamp

Estou consumindo uma API que me retorna um campo `date` com esse dado:

> 2019-02-06T14:14:38+00:00

Na minha base MySQL criei um campo `timestamp`, porque foi o único próximo que encontrei.

Bem, eu posso guardar em `varchar` mas aí tenho que ficar fazendo conversões na hora de pesquisar.

Eu posso converter o dado na hora de gravar e colocar em `timestamp` tranquilo, acontece que uso uma função que pega os nomes dos campos dinamicamente e tratar esses campos nesse momento seria um problema já que tem vários campos dessa forma com nomes diferentes.

Uma peculiaridade é que esse dado obtido na API vem com data e hora nativa do inglês que é convertida para nosso horário de verão no momento que uso no PHP:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", "2019-02-06T14:14:38+00:00");
```

Em resumo a duvida é:

Tem algum tipo de dado datetime que posso usar no MySQL que guarde a string acima e que eu não precise fazer a conversao de string para `date` num `select`?

Comment: O correto é `datetime with timezone`, sei que no postgres existe esse tipo. vc pode também gravar essa informação em um campo separado.

Comment: Pois é, eu também uso o PostgreSQL, mas nesse caso estou usando o MySQL e não vi essa opção nele. No MySQL temos os tipos DateTime e TimeStamp ambos guardam o mesmo tipo, porem na descrição do TimeStamp tem um adicional "UTC" que não sei o que significa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de falar sobre o MySQL, um pequeno resumo sobre alguns conceitos. O valor `2019-02-06T14:14:38+00:00` contém 3 informações:

- a data (`2019-02-06`)
- a hora (`14:14:38`)
- o offset (`+00:00`), que é basicamente a [diferença com relação a UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset)

Repare na letra "T" separando a data e hora. Este formato é definido pela norma [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

[UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) é o padrão a partir do qual são definidos os fusos horários. O Horário Oficial de Brasília, por exemplo, possui o offset `-03:00` (ou seja, 3 horas a menos que o UTC). Mas durante o horário de verão, o offset muda para `-02:00` (duas horas a menos que UTC). A Índia usa o offset `+05:30` (5 horas e meia a mais que o UTC) o ano todo. E por aí vai, todos os fusos horários do mundo são definidos como uma diferença com relação a UTC, além de terem o histórico de mudanças dessa diferença ao longo do tempo (quando tem horário de verão ou quando algum país decide mudar seu fuso horário).

No caso, `+00:00` significa "zero horas de diferença com relação a UTC", o que é o mesmo que dizer que esta data e hora "está em UTC".

O offset é importante para não deixar a data e hora ambíguas. Por exemplo, se tivesse apenas `2019-02-06T14:14:38` (6 de fevereiro de 2019 às 14:14:38). Esta data e hora ocorreu em instantes diferentes em cada parte do mundo. Na Austrália, as 14h do dia 6/2 ocorreram várias horas antes, se comparado ao instante em que esta mesma data e hora ocorreu no Brasil.

Usando o offset `+00:00`, eu sei o instante exato em que isso ocorreu. O detalhe é que agora, graças ao offset, `2019-02-06T14:14:38+00:00` (6 de fevereiro de 2019, 14:14:38 **em UTC**) representa um único instante, que corresponde a uma data e hora diferentes em cada parte do mundo (por exemplo, corresponde ao dia 6/2/19 às 12:14:38 em São Paulo e também ao dia **7**/2/19 às 01:14:38 em Sidnei).

---

Dito isso, [os tipos de data do MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) não possuem um suporte decente - na minha opinião - para este tipo de informação:

- O tipo `DATETIME` suporta datas e horas (mas não offsets) até o ano de 9999. Se você quer guardar a informação do offset (`+00:00`), terá que guardar em um campo separado, pois se você tiver apenas a data e hora, esta informação será ambígua (a menos que seja "aceitável" perder a informação sobre o offset, ou você assumir premissas como "sempre será UTC")
- O tipo `TIMESTAMP` suporta datas e horas (mas não offsets) até 19 de janeiro de 2038. E o ponto mais confuso é que, ao salvar as datas, estas são convertidas do timezone (fuso horário) atual para UTC, e ao consultá-las elas são convertidas de UTC para o timezone atual

Por padrão, o "timezone atual" é o do servidor no qual o MySQL está rodando, mas também pode ser setado um timezone diferente por conexão (e este será usado nas conversões). De qualquer forma, se você usar um timezone para gravar as datas e em seguida consultá-las com uma conexão que usa outro timezone, [os resultados poderão ser diferentes](https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/22599/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp-data-type/). Se alguém desconfigurar o timezone do servidor, os dados que foram gravados anteriormente serão erroneamente convertidos ao serem consultados, já que o timezone usado para gravar não é o mesmo que está sendo usado para consultar. Este é um ponto bem confuso na minha opinião.

---

Uma outra alternativa é usar o valor do [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) - não o tipo do MySQL, e sim a quantidade de segundos desde o [Unix Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (o Unix Epoch é definido como "1 de janeiro de 1970, à meia-noite em UTC"). Como este valor é um número, você pode usar `BIGINT` para guardá-lo, por exemplo.

No PHP você pode obter o valor do timestamp usando um `DateTime`:

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:sP", "2019-02-06T14:14:38+00:00");
echo $d->getTimestamp(); // 1549462478
```

E para converter este timestamp de volta para uma data:

```
// criar data a partir do timestamp
$data = new DateTime('@'. 1549462478);
```

E se quiser converter esta data para um timezone específico, use um `DateTimeZone`:

```
$data->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo'));
```

E caso queira obter o timestamp atual no MySQL, pode usar a função [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp).

Claro que isso também implica uma conversão dos valores ao se fazer as queries, mas de qualquer forma, você já ia precisar converter a string recebida pelo serviço para uma data, independente da solução escolhida.

---

Para mais informações, veja [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/409286), que possui muitas respostas boas com os prós e contras de cada opção.