# Pegar a data e hora atual aqui do Brasil para inserir no banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Tenho uma tabela que registra o login e logout dos usuários no sistema. 
Porém, quando é feito o login, a data e hora armazenados não estão sendo adicionadas de acordo com o fuso horário de Brasília.

**Segue abaixo o código**

```
<?php

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "pt_BR", "pt_BR.utf-8", "portuguese");

    /* Função para realizar o controle de login de usuários */
    function pegarLogin($conexao, $user)
    {
        $hora = date('H:i:s');
        $dia = date("Y-m-d");

        $query_login = "INSERT INTO log(tipo_reg,horario,usuario,data) VALUES('LOGIN','$hora','$user','$dia')"; 
        $resultado_query_login =  mysqli_query($conexao, $query_login);

        if(!$resultado_query_login) /*Verifica se o resultado deu certo ou errado*/
        {
            /*Se deu erro, então exibe a mensagem do sql sobre o erro */
            die("Falha no registro do login: " . mysqli_error($conexao)); 
        }

?>
```

**Imagem da tabela**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: Fiz a inserção destes dados hoje às 14:00 e pouca.

Comment: Você poderia fazer isso diretamente pelo banco através de uma `PROCEDURE` utilizando a função `now()`, já através do PHP não tenho nem ideia.

Comment: Como faria para pegar SÓ a "hora" certa de agora, utilizando o now() ?

Comment: `setlocale` só muda as configurações referentes ao idioma (formatação numérica, comparação de strings quando há acentos, etc). Talvez o que vc queira seja `date_default_timezone_set` (o resultado de `date('H:i:s')` está de acordo com o fuso do Brasil?). Lembrando ainda que a config do MySQL pode estar usando outro timezone, então a causa desta diferença pode estar lá: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/371071/112052

Comment: O resultado de date('H:i:s') não está de acordo com o fuso do Brasil.

Comment: Ah, para obter somente a hora atual no MySQL, existe a função [`CURTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curtime)

Comment: Então a princípio `date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo')` deve resolver... Ou use `CURTIME` mesmo

Comment: Eu ia falar de converter usando o `STR_TO_DATE` para pegar apenas a hora, mas seria tipo uma gambiarra com o `CURTIME` é bem melhor

Comment: O CURTIME() caiu como uma luva. Elaborem uma resposta ai para eu aceitar.

Comment: Eu conhecia o CURDATE(). Mas esse CURTIME() foi ótimo.

Comment: @hkotsubo elabore uma resposta ai. O CURTIME() me serviu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função [`setlocale`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) **não** altera as configurações referentes ao fuso horário. Segundo a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php), ela pode alterar a formatação de data e hora feita pela função [`strftime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php), mas não os valores da data e hora em si.

*Aliás, segundo a [documentação de `date`](http://example-2824), o `setlocale` é recomendado para ser usado juntamente com [`strftime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php), para formatar datas em outros idiomas.*

Sendo assim, `date` usará o fuso horário que estiver configurado no PHP, e os valores de data e hora seguirão o dia e horário atual deste fuso. O que você poderia fazer é usar [`date_default_timezone_set`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) para mudar o timezone (o fuso) do PHP, e assim `date` retornaria os valores corretos (no seu caso, poderia ser `date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo')`, por exemplo).

Outro ponto que pode ser a causa desta diferença é o timezone configurado no MySQL (conforme explicado em mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/371071/112052)).

De qualquer forma, se quer apenas o horário atual, não precisa gerá-lo no PHP. Basta usar diretamente a função [`CURTIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curtime) na sua query.