# Ordernar a tabela por data

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com uma duvida sobre como consigo pegar as compras recentes por data e hora.
Eu tentei:

```php
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `website_transactions` ORDER BY `transaction_DATE` AND `transaction_HOUR` DESC LIMIT 8");
$stmt->execute();
```

Ele ia ordernar pela hora e pela data, mas ele esta ordenando apenas pela data, sendo assim o resultado é bagunçado.

a hora esta em formato 24 horas, no caso de 00 até 23
e a data em formato Ano-Mes-Dia

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: ORDER BY `transaction_DATE` , `transaction_HOUR`

Comment: O problema é o uso indevido do AND em valores que não são lógicos. Se quer ordenar por mais de uma coluna, separe com vírgula.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema é o uso do operador lógico  `AND` indevidamente:

```
ORDER BY `transaction_DATE` AND `transaction_HOUR` DESC LIMIT 8
                            ^^^
```

Se quer ordenar por mais de uma coluna, separe por vírgula, começando sempre da rdem com mais prioridade para a menor:

```
ORDER BY expressao1, expressao2, expressao3
```

Aplicando ao seu caso:

```
SELECT * FROM `website_transactions` ORDER BY `transaction_DATE`, `transaction_HOUR` LIMIT 8
```

Se quer inverter a ordem, precisa por o `DESC` (descending) em todas as colunas que for aplicável. Exemplo:

```
nome ASC, transaction_DATE DESC, transaction_HOUR DESC
```

Neste exemplo, o nome estaria em ordem alfabética (crescente), mas a data em ordem decrescente e a hora também (a palavra ASC é dispensável, pus só para ilustrar)

Lembrando ainda que tem formatos no MySQL que armazenam data e hora, mas a conveniência de usar ou não estes formatos depende muito de como vai usar e indexar os dados.

Answer (score 2):

Por quê não manteve os DESC para os dois campos?

Está ordenando por "data asc" e somente "hora desc". Faça assim:

```
ORDER BY `transaction_DATE` DESC, `transaction_HOUR` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma mais ideal seria você deixar apenas uma coluna para armazenar esta informação... Usando o tipo `TIMESTAMP` para a coluna.

Tente modificar a sua tabela assim:

```
ALTER TABLE website_transactions DROP COLUMN transaction_DATE;
ALTER TABLE website_transactions DROP COLUMN transaction_HOUR;
ALTER TABLE website_transactions ADD transaction_date TIMESTAMP;
```

Então você poderia utilizar este código bem mais simples para realizar sua consulta

```
SELECT * FROM `website_transactions` ORDER BY `transaction_date` DESC LIMIT 8
```

Comment: De curiosidade, por que optou por `TIMESTAMP` e não `DATETIME`? Como sugestão alternativa pode ser uma boa, mas ser vantajoso ou não depende muito de como ele vai usar os valores (em especial o uso em WHERE + índices).

Comment: Eu sempre tive costume de usar TIMESTAMP, por isso optei por usar o mesmo... QUando vou inserir algum valor na tabela, eu uso CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Comment: Vale a pena uma lidinha aqui (não só na resposta aceita) para uma visão mais ampla da diferença dos dois tipos: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409286/should-i-use-the-datetime-or-timestamp-data-type-in-mysql

Comment: Fazendo "jabá" do meu post, [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/371071/112052) explica um pouco a diferença entre `DATETIME` e `TIMESTAMP`. [Aqui](https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/22599/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp-data-type/) tem um exemplo mais detalhado, e - mais um "self-jabá" - [aqui](https://github.com/hkotsubo/java-datetime-book/blob/master/src/main/java/mysql/MysqlTests.java) tem um exemplo com código (é em Java, mas a ideia é mostrar os problemas que podem acontecer com os tipos de data do MySQL)