# Guardar um valor de data no firestore

Tags: java, android, firebase, data

Estou tentando guardar um valor de data no firestore, mas estou com um problema de conversão quando pego o valor de um `EditText` e mando ele para virar um valor do tipo data. A tentativa que fiz foi essa aqui.

```
private String dateToTimestampString(String dateString){

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date parsedDate;
    Timestamp timestamp;

    try {
        parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
        timestamp = new Timestamp(parsedDate);
        return timestamp.toString();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Meu `EditText`

```
String dt = editDiasTrabalhado.getText().toString();

long dtL = Long.parseLong(dateToTimestampString(dt));

rel.setEditDiasTrabalhado(dtL);
```

O erro que esta sendo gerado é esse:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Timestamp(seconds=1563764400, nanoseconds=0)"

No campo `editDiasTrabalhado` estou setando a data atual da seguinte forma: `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Answer (score 1):

O seu método `dateToTimestampString` retorna:

```
return timestamp.toString();
```

E o [método `toString()` da classe `Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp.html#toString()) retorna uma `String` contendo o texto que aparece na exceção: `"Timestamp(seconds=1563764400, nanoseconds=0)"`.

Só que o [método `Long.parseLong` espera receber uma `String` contendo somente números](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Long.html#parseLong(java.lang.String)) (com exceção do primeiro caractere, que pode ser um sinal de `+` ou `-`). Sendo assim, a `String` que você está passando não corresponde ao formato que o método espera, e por isso o erro.

Mas talvez essa não seja a solução. Não ficou muito claro o que deve ser passado para `setEditDiasTrabalhado`. É a quantidade de dias? Se for, não faz sentido ter uma data, já que uma data representa um dia específico, e é diferente de uma quantidade de dias.

Mas se você está tentando obter o valor numérico do [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052), então você nem precisa criar o `Timestamp`. Basta usar o [`java.util.Date`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html) (que você já está obtendo através do *parsing*) e extrair este valor do mesmo:

```
private Date parseDate(String dateString) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    try {
        return dateFormat.parse(dateString);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

...
Date date = parseDate(dateString);
if (date == null) {
    ... mostrar mensagem de erro, etc
} else {
    // obter o valor do timestamp
    long dtL = date.getTime();
    ...
}
```