# Troca de dia com mês ao adicionar minutos: Por que ocorre? Como consertar?

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime, procedural

Gostaria de saber porque no código abaixo, após adicionar os 15 minutos, ocorre uma troca na ordem de dia e mês. Qual a lógica por trás disso, se é isso que estou pensando. E mais, como consertar isso em PHP Procedural (puro), sem usar truques como separar os itens e juntá-los novamente.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$inicio = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', time());
echo $inicio . '<br>';

//Define horário de expiração
$adicionaMinutos = strtotime("$inicio +15 minute");
$expiracao = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $adicionaMinutos);
echo $expiracao . '<br>';
```

Comment: Use $expiracao = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'...  e não $expiracao = date('d/m/Y H:i:s'.. https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php. O manual diz : - "A função espera que seja informada uma string contendo um formato de data em inglês US"

Answer (score 2):

A função `date`, apesar do nome, retorna uma string (que por sua vez, representa uma data em determinado formato).

Então o `$inicio` é uma string no formato "dia/mês/ano", que por sua vez é passada para `strtotime`. E [segundo a documentação de `strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#refsect1-function.strtotime-notes), quando há três números separados por barra, ele interpreta como "mês/dia/ano":

> *Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: **if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed***

Uma solução é não passar a string para `strtotime`, e sim o valor que corresponde a data (no caso, o retorno de `time`):

```php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$now = time();

$inicio = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $now);
echo $inicio . '<br>';

//Define horário de expiração
$adicionaMinutos = strtotime("@$now +15 minute");
$expiracao = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $adicionaMinutos);
echo $expiracao . '<br>';
```

Um detalhe é que, como `time()` retorna o valor numérico do [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052), então é necessário usar a `@` antes do mesmo (caso contrário o número será convertido para string e interpretado como dia, mês, ano, etc).

---

Mas claro que, como estamos lidando com números, você pode simplesmente somar a quantidade de segundos equivalente à 15 minutos (pois `time()` retorna o timestamp em segundos):

```php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$now = time();

$inicio = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $now);
echo $inicio . '<br>';

//Define horário de expiração
$expiracao = date('d/m/Y H:i:s', $now + (15 * 60)); // somando 15 minutos
echo $expiracao . '<br>';
```

Comment: Muito útil, deste detalhe eu não sabia do **@** antes do `time()`

Comment: @gleisin-dev PHP e suas bizarrices: https://ideone.com/lNnFWL

Comment: Hahaha, um mero "bêbado" processando as coisas.. Vai entender!